# What song is playing?

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

Inspired by [this xkcd](http://xkcd.com/851_make_it_better/)

[image]

You work for [Shazam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shazam_(service)) and they have a project for you. Some customers are complaining about their app taking up too much space on their phone, so they want you to code a lite version of the app. Unfortunately, your existing code can only understand the word "na", and you have to ship soon. That's okay, we'll do the best with what we've got.

## The Challenge

You must write a full program that takes a user input, or takes a command line argument, and print the title and artist of the song. Since we are trying to fix customers complaining about program size, your code must be as short as possible. The input will be a string consisting entirely of na's, with a single space between them. Lowercase/uppercase is arbitrary. This is considered a valid input: `Na Na nA na NA` This is an invalid input: `nah nah NA naNa banana` You must determine what song is playing and print it out in exactly this format:

```
Song: <trackname>
Artist: <artist>
```

If the input is *exactly* 8 na's, this matches two separate songs, so you must print both:

```
Song: Batman Theme
Artist: Neal Hefti
```

and

```
Song: Na Na Hey Hey Kiss Him Goodbye
Artist: Steam
```

If the input is *exactly* 10 na's, you must print:

```
Song: Katamari Damacy
Artist: Yuu Miyake
```

If the input is *exactly* 11 na's, you must print:

```
Song: Hey Jude
Artist: The Beatles
```

If the input is 12 or more na's, you must print

```
Song: Land Of 1000 Dances
Artist: Wilson Pickett
```

Lastly, if the input is invalid, there are less than 8 na's, or any of the words are not "na", your program fails to understand the music. So logically, there is only one other song that it could possibly be. You must print:

```
Song: Africa
Artist: Toto
```

As usual, standard loopholes apply, and the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: great background story!

Comment: Isn't Hey Jude 12 `na`s? I just listened to it and I thought it was (in terms of note lengths) `quarter quarter quarter quarter / eighth sixteenth sixteenth quarter-quarter-quarter / eighth sixteenth quarter-quarter-quarter`, which is 12 `na`s.

Comment: @Ampora `onnnnnnnnne-one-three-one-a-two-threeeeeeeeeee-one-a-two-threeeeeeee-hey-jude` definitely 11

Comment: Batman is `na na / na na / na na / na na` x2 `batman`. I noticed that the second time I saw the comic.

Comment: is `na na na` with a space in the beginning a valid input?

Comment: @TanMath for simplicity's sake, we'll say no, you don't have to handle leading spaces.

Comment: DJ MC Mayhem? You are built for this challenge, aren't you.

Comment: What about 9 `na`s? Do I print the Africa one?

Comment: @nyuszika7h yes.

Comment: I'm disturbed to find that *Na na hey hey goodbye* was by Steam and not originally Bananarama :P

Comment: It's 3 years too late to change the challenge, but I must object that the Katamari Damacy theme is titled "Katamari on the Rocks" (or if you're a purist, it's officially "Katamari on the Rocks ~ Main Theme") and thus shouldn't just be listed as just "Katamari Damacy"!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina/), 242

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=aUdgXm5hKCBuYSkqJAppTWBuYQptYF44JAo-QmF0bWFuIFRoZW1lLE5lYWwgSGVmdGkkbj5OYSBOYSBIZXkgSGV5IEtpc3MgSGltIEdvb2RieWUsU3RlYW0KbWBeMTAkCj5LYXRhbWFyaSBEYW1hY3ksWXV1IE1peWFrZQptYF4xMSQKPkhleSBKdWRlLFRoZSBCZWF0bGVzClswLTldLisKPkxhbmQgT2YgMTAwMCBEYW5jZXMsV2lsc29uIFBpY2tldHQKbWBeWzAtOV0KPkFmcmljYSxUb3RvCj4KU29uZzogCiwKJG5BcnRpc3Q6IA&input=)

```
iG`^na( na)*$
iM`na
m`^8$
>Batman Theme,Neal Hefti$n>Na Na Hey Hey Kiss Him Goodbye,Steam
m`^10$
>Katamari Damacy,Yuu Miyake
m`^11$
>Hey Jude,The Beatles
[0-9].+
>Land Of 1000 Dances,Wilson Pickett
m`^[0-9]
>Africa,Toto
>
Song: 
,
$nArtist:
```

## How it works:

IgnoreCase flag + Grep mode flag + Regex `^na( na)*$`. If the input is valid, print it as is. If not, print nothing.

```
iG`^na( na)*$
```

IgnoreCase flag + Match mode flag + Regex `na`. Count the "na"s and print the number.

```
iM`na
```

If the string is exactly "8", replace by the second line.

```
m`^8$
>Batman Theme,Neal Hefti$n>Na Na Hey Hey Kiss Him Goodbye,Steam
```

If the string is exactly "10", replace by the second line.

```
m`^10$
>Katamari Damacy,Yuu Miyake
```

If the string is exactly "11", replace by the second line.

```
m`^11$
>Hey Jude,The Beatles
```

If the string matches `[0-9].+`, replace by the second line. This is neither true for single digit numbers, `10` and `11` as they already have been repaced nor any of the above replacement strings.

```
[0-9].+
>Land Of 1000 Dances,Wilson Pickett
```

If none of the above matched, the string still starts with a number. Default to Toto, Africa.

```
m`^[0-9]
>Africa,Toto
```

Replace the placeholders `>` and `,` by `Song:` and `Artist:`.

```
>
Song: 
,
$nArtist:
```

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 276 bytes

```js
alert(`Song: `+([,`Batman Theme,Neal Hefti
Song: Na Na Hey Hey Kiss Him Goodbye,Steam`,,`Katamari Damacy,Yuu Miyake`,`Hey Jude,The Beatles`,`Land Of 1000 Dances,Wilson Pickett`][+prompt(i=0).replace(/na( |$)/gi,_=>++i)&&(i>11?4:i-7)]||`Africa,Toto`).replace(/,/g,`
Artist: `))
```

### Explanation

Input can optionally contain one trailing space.

```js
alert(                 // output the result
  `Song: `+([          // insert the "Song:" label
      ,                // set the first element to undefined in case input is empty

      // Songs
      `Batman Theme,Neal Hefti
Song: Na Na Hey Hey Kiss Him Goodbye,Steam`,
      ,
      `Katamari Damacy,Yuu Miyake`,
      `Hey Jude,The Beatles`,
      `Land Of 1000 Dances,Wilson Pickett`

    ][
      +                // if the input string was made up only of "na"s, the replace would
                       //     return a string containing only digits, making this return a
                       //     number (true), but if not, this would return NaN (false)
        prompt(        // get the input string
          i=0          // i = number of "na"s in input string
        ).replace(     // replace each "na" with a number
          /na( |$)/gi, // find each "na"
          _=>++i       // keep count of the "na"s and replace with a (non-zero) number
        )
      &&(i>11?4:i-7)   // select the song based on the number of "na"s
    ]
      ||`Africa,Toto`  // default to Africa
  ).replace(/,/g,`
Artist: `)             // insert the "Artist:" label
)
```

### Test

```js
var prompt = () => input.value;
var alert = (text) => result.textContent = text;
var solution = () => {

alert(`Song: `+([,`Batman Theme,Neal Hefti
Song: Na Na Hey Hey Kiss Him Goodbye,Steam`,,`Katamari Damacy,Yuu Miyake`,`Hey Jude,The Beatles`,`Land Of 1000 Dances,Wilson Pickett`][+prompt(i=0).replace(/na( |$)/gi,_=>++i)&&(i>11?4:i-7)]||`Africa,Toto`).replace(/,/g,`
Artist: `))

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" value="na na Na na NA na na nA" />
<button onclick="solution()">Go</button>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for 9 na's, it outputs kamari.

Comment: @RikerW Fixed. I forgot a comma...

Answer (score 4):

## PowerShell, 278 bytes

- Can handle any amount of whitespace
- No regex whatsoever!
- Implicit typecasting FTW!

```powershell
@{8='Batman Theme/Neal Hefti','Na Na Hey Hey Kiss Him Goodbye/Steam'
10='Katamari Damacy/Yuu Miyake'
11='Hey Jude/The Beatles'
12='Land Of 1000 Dances/Wilson Pickett'}[[math]::Min($args.Count*!($args|?{$_-ne'na'}),12)]|%{'Song: {0}
Artist: {1}'-f($_+'Africa/Toto'*!$_-split'/')}
```

## Ungolfed

```
@{8='Batman Theme/Neal Hefti','Na Na Hey Hey Kiss Him Goodbye/Steam' # array
10='Katamari Damacy/Yuu Miyake'
11='Hey Jude/The Beatles'
12='Land Of 1000 Dances/Wilson Pickett'} # Hashtable of songs
[   # Get value by key from hashtable
    # If key is invalid, silently return null value

    [math]::Min( # Clamp max value to 12
        $args.Count* # Multiply count of argumens
                     # true/false will be cast to 1/0
            ! # Negate result of expression
              # Will cast empty array to 'false'
              # and non-empty array to 'true'
            (
                # Return non-empty array if input arguments
                # contain anything other than 'na'
                $args | Where-Object {$_ -ne 'na'} 
            ),
        12
    )
] | ForEach-Object { # Send value from hashtable down the pipeline,
                     # This allows to process arrays in hasthable values
    'Song: {0}
    Artist: {1}' -f ( # Format string
        $_+ # Add to current pipeline variable
            'Africa/Toto'*!$_ # If pipeline variable is empty,
                              # then add default song to it
                              # Example: 'Test'*1 = 'Test'
                              #          'Test'*0 = null
        -split '/' # Split string to array for Format operator
    )
}
```

## Usage

```
PS > .\WhatSong.ps1 na na na na na na na na
Song: Batman Theme
Artist: Neal Hefti
Song: Na Na Hey Hey Kiss Him Goodbye
Artist: Steam

PS > .\WhatSong.ps1 Na na na na na na na na na Na
Song: Katamari Damacy
Artist: Yuu Miyake

PS > .\WhatSong.ps1 Na na na na na na na na na BanaNa
Song: Africa
Artist: Toto
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python <s>453</s> <s>440</s> <s>406</s> 380 bytes

**EDIT:** Thanks to Cyoce for reducing 13 bytes!

**EDIT:** Thanks again to Cyoce!

**EDIT:** Thanks to RainerP. for helping me imrpove the algorithm on certain invalid cases.

This is a rough draft of a Python program. I believe it can be definitely golfed, maybe to 300-400 bytes. But  will work on that soon.

```
f=0
S='Song:'
A='\nArtist:'
l="Batman Theme,Neal Hefti,Na Na Hey Kiss Him Goodbye,Steam,Katamari Damacy,Yuu Miyake,Hey Jude,Beatles,Land of the 1000 Dances,Wilson Pickett,Africa,Toto".split(',')
s=raw_input().lower()+" "
n=s.count("na ")
n*=n*3==len(s)
if n>11:f=8
if n==10:f=4
if n==11:f=6
if n<8or n==9:f=10
if f:print S+l[f]+A+l[f+1]
else:print S+l[0]+A+l[1]+"\n"+S+l[2]+A+l[3]
```

[Try here!](http://ideone.com/tinWZu)

Comment: Instead of that lengthy list, use `"Batman Theme,Neal Hefti,Na Na Hey Kiss Him Goodbye,Steam,Katamari Damacy,Yuu Miyake,Hey Jude,Beatles,Land of the 1000 Dances,Wilson Pickett,Africa,Toto".split(',')`

Comment: Also: instead of `if i not in ["n","a"," "]: ...` I believe you can use `if i not in 'na ': ...`. Additionally, `if f==0: somecode; else: somemorecode` can be reduced to `if f: somemorecode; else: somecode` (0 is Falsy)

Comment: Even more (I should have put these all in one, oh well): you have `"\nArtist:"` three times. try setting a variable, e.g. `A="\nArtist:"`, then using `A` in place of the string literal. The same can be done with `"Song:"`. Also,  I _think_ that `if n<8or n==9:f=10` can be moved to the top of the if statements and changed to `if n!=8:f=10`

Comment: Your program fails to detect invalid input. Output is `Batman Theme` instead of `Africa` for `na na na nan na na na na`.

Comment: @RainerP. Thank you... I knew I was missing something... I am now working on an updated algorithm

Comment: You can check the input string for validity with  `s=raw_input().lower()+" "`
`n=s.count("na ")` (Note the space after the `na`)
`n*=n*3==len(s)`. `n` will be `0` for invalid strings.

Comment: @RainerP. Thank you, but my approach is to use str.split() to create a list of n "na" 's and count them. If one of the elements is not "na", then nothing is done and n=0 as defined in the beginning. Would that cover all types of invalid input?

Comment: You won't need to set set `n` and `i` to `0` in the first line and you can drop the loop completely when using my type of check.

Comment: @RainerP. so yours is shorter?

Comment: Yes. If we add a space to the end and count `"na "` groups, the number of characters is three times the number of groups for any valid string and greater for any invalid one, so we don't need any additional checks.

Comment: Also, your solution fails on certain invalid input as we discussed above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33592/discussion-between-tanmath-and-rainer-p).

Comment: @RainerP. unless you do not want to...

Comment: You can change `raw_input()` to `input()` and request the input has quotes around it.

Answer (score 1):

## sh + coreutils, 290

Albeit longer than my other submission, this one is straightforward and pretty much ungolfed, so i included it anyway.

```
grep -Ei "^na( na)*$"|wc -w|awk '{s="Song: ";a="\nArtist: ";p=s"Africa"a"Toto"}$1==8{p=s"Batman Theme"a"Neal Hefti\n"s"Na Na Hey Hey Kiss Him Goodbye"a"Steam"}$1>9{p=s"Katamari Damacy"a"Yuu Miyake"}$1>10{p=s"Hey Jude"a"The Beatles"}$1>11{p=s"Land Of 1000 Dances"a"Wilson Pickett"}{print p}'
```

## How it works:

If the input is valid, print it as is. If not, print nothing.

```
grep -Ei "^na( na)*$"
```

Count the words.

```
wc -w
```

Simple look up table, `Song:` and `Artist:` are kept in variables.

```
awk '
    {s="Song: ";a="\nArtist: ";p=s"Africa"a"Toto"}
    $1==8{p=s"Batman Theme"a"Neal Hefti\n"s"Na Na Hey Hey Kiss Him Goodbye"a"Steam"}
    $1>9{p=s"Katamari Damacy"a"Yuu Miyake"}
    $1>10{p=s"Hey Jude"a"The Beatles"}
    $1>11{p=s"Land Of 1000 Dances"a"Wilson Pickett"}
    {print p}
'
```

Comment: I know it's been a while, but the regex can be shortened to `^(na ?)+$`.

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 325 bytes

Probably could be golfed further.

```
p(s,a)=println("Song: $s\nArtist: $a");ismatch(r"^(na )*na$",ARGS[1])&&(c=length(split(ARGS[1],"na"))-1)==8?(p("Batman Theme","Neal Hefti"),p("Na Na Hey Hey Kiss Him Goodbye","Steam")):c==10?p("Katamari Damacy","Yuu Miyake"):c==11?p("Hey Jude","The Beatles"):c>=12?p("Land Of 1000 Dances","Wilson Pickett"):p("Africa","Toto")
```

Comment: I know it's been a while, but the regex can be shortened to `^(na ?)+$`.

Comment: Also, the checks can be shortened a bit by using `<` and `>` instead of `==`: `&&(c=length(split(ARGS[1],"na"))-1)<9?(p("Batman Theme","Neal Hefti"),p("Na Na Hey Hey Kiss Him Goodbye","Steam"))c>11?p("Land Of 1000 Dances","Wilson Pickett"):c>10?p("Hey Jude","The Beatles"):c>9?p("Katamari Damacy","Yuu Miyake"):p("Africa","Toto")`. Off-topic: I like your Avatar. Finished watching SAO last week. ;)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>403</s> <s>395</s> <s>370</s> <s>365</s> <s>364</s> 362 bytes

-8 -5 -1 = -14 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

Pretty much as straight-forward as can be.

```c
f(char*s){int*a[]={"Neal Hefti","Steam","Yuu Miyake","The Beatles","Wilson Pickett","Toto","Batman Theme","Na Na Hey Hey Kiss Him Goodbye","Katamari Damacy","Hey Jude","Land Of 1000 Dances","Africa"},i,l=0,j=1;for(;*s;s+=3-!s[2])i=(*s|32)^'n'|(s[1]|32)^97|s[2]>32,l++;for(i=i?5:l^8?l^10?l^11?l>11?4:5:3:2:j++;j--;)printf("Song: %s\nArtist: %s\n",a[6+i--],a[i]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZB9a9swEMb/bj7FzTBqJza17HXLbNyQMljoSzroYIzEgasjt5fIcrGUQkjy2VPZKaQNK3TmrNPpfs9zQpl3n2XbbW5nD1i1lbMiqds4SpOVNeQoYMBzTZZr3WqOhcl/Fwu4piXOuSl@P3A456gFV6b6Q0KVEn5RNuda1@1Slyadoy5QgoGLWjREMDHgy@a/JKVgQAX8LMvp3bIGLlFjgRXBD5OypTmpwYvFtG5eoZzCTQ7M930DyKwZ3c8rytDauOSKxHdnCYvzsrLjtopVJwm9T2oUpA4ldlutw8CZHMvjta1GLG2q79/Wdf8sDFzR6TRKSqh3GolJtycmzK8X1hNnZvkSnUZhFEQzA848L3YeK/NiuW3dlvI@gs9qLPuVJqV3e8vF0dcOeV5qNpQ68WZrcCiQpO20Vq2jx4VWttUFm@QTCpo6Y@mZz3Li1pFxnZfVk0R4Jxpq5zCW4XseEu9Q4gEdHDI7Ozg5gWBPMf8f2GEM97ep5czf67sfkMs@vCi7rwazjyjfvEQzm72yCP/P4q1R2NpsnwE)

Comment: @ceilingcat Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, <del>501</del> 477 bytes

```
fn main(){let(mut i,mut n)=(String::new(),0);let(s,a);std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut i);i=i.trim().to_lowercase();let o=i.split(" ");for w in o{if w!="na"{n=0;break}else{n+=1}}match n{8=>{println!("Song: Batman Theme\nArtist: Neal Hefti");s="Na Na Hey Hey Kiss Him Goodbye";a="Steam"}10=>{s="Katamari Damacy";a="Yuu Miyake"}11=>{s="Hey Jude";a="The Beatles"}_=>{if n>=12{s="Land Of 1000 Dances";a="Wilson Pickett"}else{s="Africa";a="Toto"}}}print!("Song: {}\nArtist: {}",s,a)}
```

Ungolfed

```
fn main() {
    let (mut input_string, mut na_counter) = (String::new(), 0);
    let (song_name, artist_name);

    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut input_string);
    input_string = input_string.trim().to_lowercase();
    let output = input_string.split(" ");

    for word in output {
        if word != "na" {
            na_counter = 0;
            break;
        } else {
            na_counter += 1;
        }
    }

    match na_counter {
        8 => {
            println!("Song: Batman Theme\nArtist: Neal Hefti");
            song_name = "Na Na Hey Hey Kiss Him Goodbye";
            artist_name = "Steam";
        }
        10 => {
            song_name = "Katamari Damacy";
            artist_name = "Yuu Miyake";
        }
        11 => {
            song_name = "Hey Jude";
            artist_name = "The Beatles";
        }
        _ => {
            if na_counter >= 12 {
                song_name = "Land Of 1000 Dances";
                artist_name = "Wilson Pickett";
            } else {
                song_name = "Africa";
                artist_name = "Toto";
            }
        }
    }

    print!("Song: {}\nArtist: {}", song_name, artist_name);
}
```

Edit: removed an unnecessary to_string and type annotations

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>312</s> 292 bytes

```perl
$_=lc<>;$n="(na ?)";/^(na ){7}na$|(na ){9,}na/ or$_="%Africa&Toto";s/$n{12,}/%Land Of 1000 Dances&Wilson Pickett/;s/$n{11}/%Hey Jude&The Beatles/;s/$n{10}/%Katamari Damacy&Yuu Miyake/;s/$n{8}/%Batman Theme&Neal Hefti\n%Na Na Hey Hey Kiss Him Goodbye&Steam/;s/&/\nArtist: /g;s/%/Song: /g;print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NVB/S8NADP0qobSHg8G1gvijTukQLE47YQMRhhLbdB5rc6N3/aPMffZ6rRMSeC/v5QWyp6a66Hv/c1blt3exzzPvjBHuJ14sPwY0OVweGf2fP3w9dUSCbtyCFyRlo3IUa221Fxvp8yE6nx5l8IxcwLKEKAxDeEDOyYg3VRnN8KryHVkrT/bIuVPq4KktSKy/CeaEtiLzr4dOX6DFGhvlkmrMO/HetvCiOtzRyXXlTHO0NTK4iJpERlhBSqVVGw4yBFfDkaEXyhhIVQ2PWhdfHYmVJayHICE3nDRWGXsDcusGgVxp3o5k3yi2fe9ewGPaABLIkhHgLw)

Ungolfed:

```perl
$_ = lc <STDIN>;
$_ =~ /^(na ){7}na$|(na ){9,}na/ or $_ = "%Africa&Toto";
$_ =~ s/(na ?){12,}/%Land Of 1000 Dances&Wilson Pickett/;
$_ =~ s/(na ?){11}/%Hey Jude&The Beatles/;
$_ =~ s/(na ?){10}/%Katamari Damacy&Yuu Miyake/;
$_ =~ s/(na ?){8}/%Batman Theme&Neal Hefti\n%Na Na Hey Hey Kiss Him Goodbye&Steam/;
$_ =~ s/&/\nArtist: /g;
$_ =~ s/%/Song: /g;
print $_
```

Comment: I missed some cases, working on a fix now

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pa`, 248 bytes

```perl
$_=/^(na ?)+$/&&(@F==8?",Batman Theme;Neal Hefti,Na Na Hey Hey Kiss Him Goodbye;Steam":@F==10?"Katamari Damacy;Yuu Miyake":@F==11?",Hey Jude;The Beatles":@F>11?",Land Of 1000 Dances;Wilson Pickett":0)||",Africa;Toto";s/;/
Artist: /gm;s/,/
Song: /gm
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9BS8NAEIXv/RXDUkqLkd0cBMkSY4tosFqFFsSLMiaTujS7G7KbQ6C/3bgJHoU3DDNv@B7TUFtfDcP8M@UfS4OQrS7mfLFY3t6n6XXGog16jQYO36RJ7ghryKnyKtohBOXUT7VVzkGuNDxYW371JPeeULNkpMQiY1v0qLFVcBda0cv3roNn1eOJ/m7iEDWCHruSZAiDDaGvyY32zeQ@oSnhpYJYCBEwpiAn31TtrIFXVZzIe5aI1fnMonXVqgLlwXrLpOOSz9atV84nwI86LCI@21tznMZhCD//px/beGWNGy4b/AU)

Answer (score 1):

## UNIX Shell, 394 bytes

```sh
uudecode -p<<<'begin-base64 0 -
/Td6WFoAAATm1rRGAgAhARwAAAAQz1jM4AE9AIRdACmbycaLOYv90Azj3HBohRZGa6a5FikeJU+8JbGlB4f9wmi2aQ+mn81aypMRM4nEKPxW439Z2C4WfGeyrREjk427H1GrCRUMHdth+9lVBDiPfCaD8WpStyS0MtJenHKB+tou8rD9INq0yw9IPXuQe7zLM3p14ZDFO8UoJp66scd4bKQAAACSwUb7ERvesgABoAG+AgAARAEAGbHEZ/sCAAAAAARZWg==
===='|unxz|sed -n $#s/,/\\n/gp|grep .||echo $'Song: Land Of 1000 Dances\nArtist: Wilson Pickett'
```

Test:

```sh
; sh $THE_FILE na na na na na na na
Song: Batman Theme
Artist: Neil Hefti

Song: Na Na Hey Kiss Him Goodbye
Artist: Steam
```

Probably could be optimized, but I just liked this idea TBH :)

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice first answer! Do be aware that a lot of answers use [TryItOnline](https://tio.run), a free language interpreter, to demonstrate their programs running. I'm not too familiar with UNIX Shell, but I'm sure you could add a link to such a site to allow others to test your code

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 353 bytes

```java
s->{int n=s.split(" ").length,b=s.matches("(na ?)+")?1:0;s="Africa";return"Song: "+(b>0?n<8?s:n<9?"Batman Theme\nArtist: Neal Hefti\nSong: Na Na Hey Hey Kiss Him Goodbye":n>11?"Land of 1000 Dances":n>10?"Hey Jude":n>9?"Katamari Damacy":"":s)+"\nArtist: "+(b>0?n<8?"Toto":n<9?"Steam":n>11?"Wilson Pickett":n>10?"The Beatles":n>9?"Yuu Miyake":"":"Toto");}
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##lVNRa9tADH7frxD3ZJPVOG@b3cSkDBbW1QxSGGPtg3y@JNfYuuCTC6bkt2eK7a4ttGwFCe4kff50@uQ7vMcztzd0V@6OukLv4QotPXwAsMSmWaM2kJ@uACtuLG1AB@PBh6nED@JinpGthhwIZnD0Z/MHwQPNfOT3leVAgQqjytCGtx8LidbIemt8oAJCyMKJCrNpEqd@phbrxmpUaWO4bUitHG0SUJOgmMcZnX/KfELnnzN1gVwjwfXW1OaGFg1bzwnkBitYmjXbGxqQOZ5sabreL628cGlr@OpcWXRGJTSfTjP1HakEt4ZpHMfwBUkb36fiTJ1g39qyLxXeS2SssbFSVaPuVKJU4qX/px6e9aquHTs1NLxig/Uj309beUfww@qdYX6kksfAhUGuBnYB/WpbuLId7kxPNHwvTA/HdBj7vi0qGfs4/XtnS6hFv1Gi37cYDtqx8aKBjPo1U72Q/yh6d@m7q98EvIwWFcLoLxMiMy0gXwiih23/l16Ni/y0xv0ge9jfXR//gc6zqSPXcrSXBFcU@InoMjK9kqZIBz58Oz9yH45/AA)

```java
s->{                             // Method with String as both parameter and return-type
  int n=s.split(" ").length,     //  The amount of words when split by spaces
      b=s.matches("(na ?)+")?1:0;//  Whether the input matches the regex "^(na ?)+$"
  s="Africa";                    //  Set the input we no longer need to "Africa"
  return"Song: "                 //  Return "Song: "
    +(b>0?                       //   +If the input matched the regex:
       n<8?                      //     If there are less than 8 "na"'s: 
        s                        //      Append "Africa"
       :n<9?                     //     Else-if there are exactly 8 "na"'s:
        "Batman Theme\nArtist: Neal Hefti\nSong: Na Na Hey Hey Kiss Him Goodbye"
                                 //      Append the String above
       :n>11?                    //     Else-if there are 12 or more "na"'s:
        "Land of 1000 Dances"    //      Append "Land of 1000 Dances"
       :n>10?                    //     Else-if there are exactly 11 "na"'s:
        "Hey Jude"               //      Append "Hey Jude"
       :n>9?                     //     Else-if there are exactly 10 "na"'s:
        "Katamari Damacy"        //      Append "Katamari Damacy"
       :                         //     Else (there are exactly 9 "na"'s):
        ""                       //      Append nothing
      :                          //    Else:
       s)                        //     Append "Africa"
    +"\nArtist: "                //   +Append a new-line and "Artist: "
    +(b>0?                       //   +If the input matched the regex:
       n<8?                      //     If there are less than 8 "na"'s:
        "Toto"                   //      Append "Toto"
       :n<9?                     //     Else-if there are exactly 8 "na"'s:
        "Steam"                  //      Append "Steam"
       :n>11?                    //     Else-if there are 12 or more "na"'s:
        "Wilson Pickett"         //      Append "Wilson Pickett"
       :n>10?                    //     Else-if there are exactly 11 "na"'s:
        "The Beatles"            //      Append "The Beatles"
       :n>9?                     //     Else-if there are exactly 10 "na"'s:
        "Yuu Miyake"             //      Append "Yuu Miyake"
       :                         //     Else (there are exactly 9 "na"'s):
        ""                       //      Append nothing
      :                          //    Else:
       "Toto");}                 //     Append "Toto"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 148 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
l#„naQW*O5Ý8+@OI5£“‹…0Toto
ßƒ›Ì0Neal Hefti0ÿ¤·¤··—„š‚¿bye0ÁÜ

KatamariÊÖacy0Yuu Miyake
¤· Jude0€€ÊÄ
ˆÑ€‚ 2–›s0¦‹šèett“¶¡0δ¡2₄:¬2ǝ„ŽŸŒá#ÞrèðδÛø„: ý»™
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##NU6xSgNBEO33KxbSabMcBCSV6dRgQkAQy42ucBjvINkrrlvDYSE2RrGISWRVQooUFiGJSgjMcFoI@Yj5kcueILyBebyZ917Ylg1fZVmzQGYYyPrxVq2Ig53t3dp@EV7J9Ml8kBmJo1CHDJ@/u2Q@8VZUlWzyPXWufYEreIP538zJPDib1JLpwaoRK4FX2GesIrW8lC0fb/BRnsbiJIr4oR/LC8XyP34QnSlBnYmDO0nY7zXe5dT0uEfm3kW2BYxck9TiWGntasEMrFhPwXrUSUow8X4GefIyXaRdtAUctnCM7@spPuHCCSWOS/ii5CXLqpI7BGUeuKXM/@kG) or [verify some more test cases](https://tio.run/##jU5NS0JBFN3Prxh0Vy4GQQg35q4PUoIgWo410SMbQ@cFD1pMIi2iTRYtTI1XIS5ctBC1QoS5vFoE/oj5I68Z3dhCC86Fc@85955bKNGcw8Lzs8g6P3VFEkdSXgxFsq6YdjEvzEe1bHK6vbuUTUBjZXk16yXUs5Z1Ld@0bJGdgiggePysavkO1yTDaB6vsUPhEBipF9WfVF/LO3Mm8LWsqVHOYwQuoI7QJhX0hBYduIJ7uu@RPdfFW45Hjxmye3jDPWBElzsGxlJB35dwY1tZw3Etb01kiaiW@STwoc2EMG@pnvLJuKv8uC5XkqoT/2rY5GEwCKrgR6FZhDa8jrvwAAMjJDEM1YeuPIUx1UuFnKIMxQY8jbkhacTpEbaVsQMj5Cin1jXVJ8YZPm@O569M@WLV8D8Ni9J/83/aLJ/BDw).

**Explanation:**

```python
l            # Convert the (implicit) input-string to lowercase
 #           # Split it on spaces (if there are any)
  „naQ       # Check for each word if it's equal to "na" (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
      W      # Push its minimum, without popping the list itself
       *     # Multiply that to all integers
             # (if any word wasn't "na", the entire list now only contains 0s)
        O    # Sum this list to get the amount of "na"s
5Ý           # Push the list [0,1,2,3,4,5]
  8+         # Add 8 to each: [8,9,10,11,12,13]
    @        # Check for each if the sum is larger than or equal to this value
             # (1 if sum>=n, 0 if sum<n)
     O       # Sum to get the amount of truthy values
I            # Push the input-string
 5£          # Pop and only leave its first 5characters (if it's a valid string,
             # this will be "na na" - with variable casing)
   “‹…0Toto
    ßƒ›Ì0Neal Hefti0ÿ¤·¤··—„š‚¿bye0ÁÜ
    
    KatamariÊÖacy0Yuu Miyake
    ¤· Jude0€€ÊÄ
    ˆÑ€‚ 2–›s0¦‹šèett“
             # Push dictionary string "africa0 Toto\nbatman theme0Neal Hefti0ÿ hey hey kiss him goodbye0 steam\n\nKatamari damarcy0Yuu Miyake\nhey Jude0 the beatles\nland of 2 dances0 wilson pickett",
             # where the `ÿ` is automatically replaced with the 5-char string
¶¡           # Split this string on newlines
  0δ¡        # And then split each inner string on 0s
             #  [["africa"," Toto"],
             #   ["batman theme","Neal Hefti","na na hey hey kiss him goodbye"," steam"],
             #   [],
             #   ["Katamari damarcy","Yuu Miyake"],
             #   ["hey Jude"," the beatles"],
             #   ["land of 2 dances"," wilson pickett"]]
     2₄:     # Replace the 2 with 1000
        ¬    # Get the first pair (without popping): ["africa"," Toto"]
         2ǝ  # Insert it at (0-based) index 2, replacing the empty list
„ŽŸŒá        # Push dictionary string "song artist"
     #       # Split it on spaces: ["song","artist"]
      Þ      # Cycle this list infinitely: ["song","artist","song","artist",...]
r            # Reverse the values on the stack
 è           # Modulair 0-based index the sum of truthy values into the list of lists of
             # artist(s)/song(s), so 6 will wrap back to the first item
   δ         # Map over each string inside each inner list:
  ð Û        #  And trim all leading spaces
     ø       # Create pairs with the infinitely cycled list, where it will only create
             # as many pairs as the smallest list (so either 2 or 4 in this case)
      „: ý   # Join each inner pair with ": " delimiter
          »  # Then join everything by newlines
           ™ # And finally titlecase each word in the string
             # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `“‹…0Toto ßƒ›Ì0Neal Hefti0ÿ¤·¤··—„š‚¿bye0ÁÜ\n\nKatamariÊÖacy0Yuu Miyake\n¤· Jude0€€ÊÄ\nˆÑ€‚ 2–›s0¦‹šèett“` is `"africa0 Toto\nbatman theme0Neal Hefti0ÿ hey hey kiss him goodbye0 steam\n\nKatamari damarcy0Yuu Miyake\nhey Jude0 the beatles\nland of 2 dances0 wilson pickett"` and `„ŽŸŒá` is `"song artist"`.