# A crowd of blank stares

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

## Problem

Given no input write a program or a function that outputs or returns the following string:

`(<(<>(<>.(<>.<(<>.<>(<>.<>)<>.<>)>.<>).<>)<>)>)`

## Rules

- Shortest program wins.
- Trailing whitespace allowed.
- Trailing newlines allowed.
- Unused parameters for functions allowed.

Comment: Note: this string is the concatenation of substrings of `(<>.<>)`: `"(<" + "(<>" + "(<>." + ... + "(<>.<>)" + "<>.<>)" + ">.<>)" + ... + ">)"`

Comment: This would've been a little less "hardcode all the text!" if it were a bigger crowd...

Comment: @totallyhuman Will think about it next time

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
pΙ2○3V?hG]‘Γ
```

Explanation:

```
pΙ2○3V?hG]‘   Push compressed string of the first half of the string (this is the kind of thing this compressor was made for)
           Γ  mirror, swap chars & palindromize with one character overlap
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=cCV1MDM5OTIldTI1Q0IzViUzRmhHJTVEJXUyMDE4JXUwMzkz)

Comment: Nice to see you have an online interpreter available now :)

Comment: How do you do this? Great work though!!

Answer (score 18):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 16 bytes

```
"(<>.".∞ηJÀ24£.∞
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fScPGTk9J71HHvHPbvQ43GJkcWgzi/P8PAA)

**Explanation**

```
"(<>."             # push this string
                   # STACK: "(<>."
      .∞           # intersected mirror
                   # STACK: "(<>.<>)"
        η          # compute prefixes
         J         # join to string
                   # STACK: "((<(<>(<>.(<>.<(<>.<>(<>.<>)"
          À        # rotate left
           24£     # take the first 24 chars
                   # STACK: "(<(<>(<>.(<>.<(<>.<>(<>."
              .∞   # intersected mirror
                   # STACK: "(<(<>(<>.(<>.<(<>.<>(<>.<>)<>.<>)>.<>).<>)<>)>)"
```

Answer (score 16):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 49 bytes

```python
for i in range(11):print(end='(<>.<>)'[i-12:i+2])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw9BQ06qgKDOvRCM1L8VWXcPGTs/GTlM9OlPX0MgqU9soVvP/fwA)

Answer (score 15):

## JS (Jsfuck), 10,614 bytes

Didn't have access to the website, had to figure this all out manually -.-

```
(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]])[+!+[]+(+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[])]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]]
+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]])[+!+[]+(+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[])]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+!+[]]
+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]])[+!+[]+(+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[])]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+!+[]]
+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]
+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]])[+!+[]+(+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[])]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+!+[]]
+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]]
+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]])[+!+[]+(+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[])]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+!+[]]
+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+!+[]]
+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]])[+!+[]+(+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[])]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+!+[]]
+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+!+[]]
+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]])[+!+[]+(+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[])]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+!+[]]
+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+!+[]]
+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]])[+!+[]+(+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[])]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+!+[]]
+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+!+[]]
+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]])[+!+[]+(+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[])]
+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+!+[]]
+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]])[+!+[]+(+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[])]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+!+[]]
+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]])[+!+[]+(+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[])]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+!+[]]
+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]])[+!+[]+(+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[])]
```

## Explanation:

Most of the characters are relatively easy:
 For the brackets im executing

```
   ([]["fill"]+[])[13] // '('

   ([]["fill"]+[])[14] // ')'
```

The full stop is gotten by making js create a scientific notation number like
 1.1e+21 
 And taking the dot character after converting to a string

The square brackets are harder, we have to execute the function to create an 
 italic html object string and steal the angle brackets. The main trick in this is getting the 'c' for the word italics, which requires building up another function to take the c from 'function'

There's a lot of scope for improvement here, mostly on which functions are used to get the square brackets. I also recall an easier way to get the character 'c' if italics is better, but i'd have to look though my old files to find it

```js
console.log( (!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]])[+!+[]+(+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[])]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]]
+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]])[+!+[]+(+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[])]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+!+[]]
+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]])[+!+[]+(+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[])]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+!+[]]
+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]
+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]])[+!+[]+(+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[])]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+!+[]]
+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]]
+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]])[+!+[]+(+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[])]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+!+[]]
+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+!+[]]
+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]])[+!+[]+(+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[])]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+!+[]]
+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+!+[]]
+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]])[+!+[]+(+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[])]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+!+[]]
+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+!+[]]
+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]])[+!+[]+(+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[])]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+!+[]]
+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+!+[]]
+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]])[+!+[]+(+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[])]
+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+!+[]]
+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]])[+!+[]+(+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[])]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+!+[]]
+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]])[+!+[]+(+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[])]
+(+[]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+!+[]]
+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]])[+!+[]+(+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[])])
```

Comment: This looks overly-long even for JSFuck but +1 for the sheet effort of doing this manually.

Comment: I call BS on doing it manually. You had to have done _something_ to automate generating that.

Comment: 10660 bytes actually.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I bet he figured it out manually and used the powers of ctrlc and v

Comment: @PatrickRoberts It's not a super difficult program, its just a case of understanding how to build up each character. As a basic example, the way to get a 't' character is to make an empty array '[]', cast to a number to make the number 0:  '+[]' and then apply the not operator to it to cast to a boolean true '!+[]'. Then cast to a string, by adding an empty array again and putting it in brackets to give us the string "true" '(!+[]+[])' and finally take the zeroth letter with '(!+[]+[])[+[]]'

Comment: Why do you need square brackets?

Comment: @CalculatorFeline what do you mean? Are you suggesting its possible for just the characters '()+!' to be turing complete then i'm not sure, but i'm much more familiar with the '[]()!+' system

Comment: `()+!` isn't Turing complete because no literals exist. I meant why do you need to construct square brackets `[]`?

Comment: @CalculatorFeline ah right yes I mean '<' and '>', not sure what the proper name is. maybe angle brackets

Comment: Correct. And yeah, `<>` seem quite hard to make D: Maybe you should try making a `<u>` element rather than an `<i>` element (`u`=`([][[]]+[])[+[]]`)

Comment: @CalculatorFeline I'd need to build up the name of the function. Here i'm making the string function 'italics()'. Your comment did prompt me looking into shorter words, I think bold() may be easier to create

Comment: Forgot about that :P Also, what browser are you using? Chrome 58 doesn't have `italics` or `bold`.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline chrome version 58, italics seems to work ok here, just ran "a".italics() in the console

I have to go for today, i will speak more tomorrow

Comment: Oh, I thought it was a global function. Good to know. `sup` and `sub` seem like good candidates (hardest chars are `p` and `b`)

Comment: My semiautogenerated solution is 11846 bytes. Well, time to start golfing :P (Also, I'm using `alert`. Calculating with `console.log` now)

Comment: 13169 bytes with `console.log`. Clearly not the way to go.

Comment: Wait a moment. Is this a function? Well, doesn't make much of a difference for me (~100 bytes)

Comment: @CalculatorFeline I'll see if I have a good solution for p or b written down in a notepad file somewhere to make sub or sup now

Comment: Also, now that you have access to the website (?), maybe you should take a look.

Answer (score 12):

## [C# (Mono)](http://www.mono-project.com/), <s>54</s> 52 bytes

```cs
s=>"(<(<>(<>.(<>.<(<>.<>(<>.<>)<>.<>)>.<>).<>)<>)>)"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYyxCsIwEIZn8xRHpwS0uCcNSMFJJwcHcUhjKJE2kV4iSOmzx9hswt338x/cp3E3eudTROt6uHwwmJETPShEOMyEvGI3WA0YVMhxjE4L3z2NDtt8m/KPVNAkbGRFBRUyT/1bsUIWssIVpTLJqsT/5G9vH3BW1tFivt1BTT0ymMmm9Q79YOrrZIM5WWeoonvGOFnIkr4)

*-2 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen*

RIP C#

Comment: I know the feeling (Java). But, you can save two bytes. The trailing `;` isn't counted for lambda-answers. And `()` can be replaced with a single character (unused `null` object). [Relevant meta post for the second.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12681/are-we-allowed-to-use-empty-input-we-wont-use-when-no-input-is-asked-regarding)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Yes I did specify unused function parameters allowed so `s=>` is perfectly fine.

Comment: -1: There was no effort done to golf the answer in any way.

Comment: @MechMK1 that's the point, it's quite literally as golfed as possible in C#. Literal output of the string is the tersest way to output this particular string in this particular language. See [Erlantz's C# answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127455/44998)

Comment: @Skidsdev I still consider that it's against the spirit of Code Golf, boring to write and boring to read. I mean, my vote doesn't count because I don't actively participate, so don't worry about that. It's just my 2 cents, so to say.

Answer (score 11):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 30 bytes

```
(<>.<>)
5`.
$&$'
7`.
$`$&
^.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fS8PGTs/GTpPLNEGPS0VNRZ3LHMRIUFHjitPj@v8fAA)

Comment: um what even is this

Answer (score 7):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>28</s> <s>27</s> <s>25</s> 22 bytes

3? 4? bytes thanks to @KritixiLithos

```
i(<>.<>)òÙxlHÄ$xGòxÍî
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P1PDxk7Pxk5T@vCmwzMrcjwOt6hUuB/eVHG49/C6//8B)

```
i(<>.<>)                'insert (<>.<>)
         ò        ò      'recursively
          Ù              'duplicate this (bottom line) down
           x             'delete the first character
            l            'and break when there's only one character left
             H           'go to the top of the buffer
              Ä          'duplicate that line up
               $x        'delete the last character
                 G       'and go back to the bottom of the buffer
                   x     'delete the extra ) left by the loop
                    Íî   'and remove all newlines
```

Comment: You can replace `hx` with just `X`.

Comment: And `dkHxògJ` is 1 byte shorter than `dkVHgJ0x`.

Comment: Yeah DJ's `Íî` thing works too

Comment: I get `i(<>.<>)òÙxlHÄ$xGòddÍî` for 23

Comment: @KritixiLithos I literally JUST switched the `lX` for `xl` too :D

Answer (score 7):

## Charcoal, <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
Ｆ⁶…(<>.<>)⁺²ι‖ＢＯ⁷
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExCoAwDADA3VcUpwTUwUEHxcE@QPEHpaRUCFZiK/j6eOejE58cq4YkBgY0u5xXBvt5JhvTDTXMSzcvWDdm5/JA35gTEafqoMDk81pyJgn8bS8JuxtGnFS1fbV9@Ac) Link is to verbose version of code. <s>Uses the new Slice operator.</s>

Comment: [Compression is also 17 bytes now :P](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRENJw0bDxg6I9EDYBkyAuUqaXEGpaTmpySVOpSUlqUVpOZUamv///9ct@69bnAMA)

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 42 bytes

```r
cat(substring('(<>.<>)',-4:6,2:12),sep='')
```

Fairly simple program that takes advantage of the way substring works in R.  So `substring('(<>.<>)',-4:6,2:12)` produces the following vector

```r
> substring('(<>.<>)',-4:6,2:12)
 [1] "(<"      "(<>"     "(<>."    "(<>.<"   "(<>.<>"  "(<>.<>)" "<>.<>)"  ">.<>)"  
 [9] ".<>)"    "<>)"     ">)"
```

`cat` with an empty separator outputs it to STDOUT in the required format.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKO4NKm4pCgzL11DXcPGTs/GTlNdR9fEykzHyMrQSFOnOLXAVl1d8/9/AA)

Answer (score 5):

## TrumpScript, 70 Bytes

I know, it's a boring solution.

```
say "(<(<>(<>.(<>.<(<>.<>(<>.<>)<>.<>)>.<>).<>)<>)>)"
America is great
```

Comment: Well done, nonetheless.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 14 bytes

```
"(<>.<>)"aᶠckb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/X0nDxk7Pxk5TKfHhtgXJ2Un///@PAgA)

```
"(<>.<>)"           #   string
         aᶠ         #       get all Affixes (pre- and suffixes)
           c        #       Concatenate
            kb      #       remove last (Knife) and first (Behead)
```

Comment: As of now the full face seems to get duplicated, but you can fix it by just changing the `ᶠ` into a `ᵘ`.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>59</s> 57 bytes

<s>2</s> 4 bytes less than a simple `puts()` solution. There is sure to be some elegant recursive solution, but so far the overhead becomes too large at every attempt.

```c
f(i){for(i=1;i++<12;)printf("%.*s",i,"(<>.<>)"+i/7*i%7);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1OzOi2/SCPT1tA6U1vbxtDIWrOgKDOvJE1DSVVPq1hJJ1NHScPGTs/GTlNJO1PfXCtT1VzTuvY/UIlCbmJmngZQvwZIAAA)

Answer (score 3):

## Brainfuck, <s>198</s> <s>175</s> 167 Bytes

I have never done a codegolf, so this is my first one. Feedback is highly appreciated.

```
++++[>+++++<-]>[>++>+++>+++>++>++[<]>-]>.>.<.>.>++.<<.>.>.>>++++++.<<<<.>.>.>>.<<<.<.>.>.>>.<<<.>.<<.>.>.>>.<<<.>.>+.<<.>.>>.<<<.>.>.<.>>.<<<.>.>.>.<<<.>.>.<<.>.>.<.>.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGwii7UCkto1urB2ICeJBMRBF28TaASX07PRsgBgooGcDZujZQXSB@HAREFsPhWOnZ4PGt4OZABcA6UBwkIThsnr//wMA)

I went for the most obvious solution in my opinion. First, I set cells 1-5 to one of the letters "().<>". Then I just go to the right cells and output the character.

UPDATE: I changed the order in which the characters appear on the "tape" making the program way shorter and more efficient.

UPDATE 2: Just revisited my post after a while and realized, that using a shorter sequence for setting up the cells I could save some bytes.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! :)

Comment: Nice, first answer, usually answers that are not immediately apparent how they work need an explanation but this challenge is pretty trivial so not really needed. But if you do a 1200 bytes brainfuck in the future just a simple explanation goes a long way.

Comment: I will be sure to do that in the future.

Comment: Ok, I added a short (and kinda bad) description of my code.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 20 bytes

```
Ａ(<>ι(<ιι.ι.<ι.ιι.‖Ｂ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9noUaNnbndmrYnNt5bqceENmAKSDxqGHa@z2L/v8HAA)

Thanks to [Destructible Lemon](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55896/destructible-lemon) for noticing a pattern (-4).

AST:

```
Program
├Ａ: Assign
│├'(<>': String '(<>'
│└ι: Identifier ι
├Print
│└'(<': String '(<'
├Print
│└ι: Identifier ι
├Print
│└ι: Identifier ι
├Print
│└'.': String '.'
├Print
│└ι: Identifier ι
├Print
│└'.<': String '.<'
├Print
│└ι: Identifier ι
├Print
│└'.': String '.'
├Print
│└ι: Identifier ι
├Print
│└ι: Identifier ι
├Print
│└'.': String '.'
└‖Ｂ: Reflect butterfly
 └Multidirectional
```

What `‖Ｂ` does is basically visually palindromize canvas.

Comment: Explanation please.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline Added AST as returned by `-a`.

Comment: Huh. That was more useful than I thought.

Comment: I think this would be clearer even if you just added that print is implicit with objects

Comment: @DestructibleLemon But the AST already has the `Print`s in there, not sure what you mean.

Comment: I know. it would just clarify why there are a bunch of print commands out of nowhere for someone who doesn't know the language

Comment: Wait a minute I got it wrong and this is bugged

Comment: @DestructibleLemon Basically the AST says that those `Print`s are implied by itself.

Comment: `Ａ(<>.ι(<(<>ιι<ι<>ι‖Ｂ` actually works

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 47 bytes

```js
g=(i=2)=>i>12?'':'(<>.<>)'.slice(i-14,i)+g(i+1)
f=(i=11)=>i?f(i-1)+'(<>.<>)'.slice(i-13,i+1):''

// Both of the above work and are the same size

document.write('<pre>Actual g(): ' + g() + '\nActual f(): ' + f() + '\nExpected:   (<(<>(<>.(<>.<(<>.<>(<>.<>)<>.<>)>.<>).<>)<>)>)</pre>');
```

Uses the same method as [Rod's Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127443/48878) answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 61 bytes

I know this is lame but it's much shorter than my other solution...

```c
f(){puts("(<(<>(<>.(<>.<(<>.<>(<>.<>)<>.<>)>.<>).<>)<>)>)");}
```

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 103 bytes

Here's a version where I'm trying to be somewhat tricky...

```c
char*e="(<>.<>)<>.<>)>.<>).<>)<>)>)";f(i,n){for(n=2;n<8;n++)for(i=0;i<n;i++)putchar(e[i]);puts(&e[i]);}
```

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>117</s> 115 bytes

A recursive version that's fully tricky...

```c
char*e="(<>.<>)";main(i,j){if(i<6){for(++i,j=0;j<i;putchar(e[j++]));main(i);}else if(i<12)printf(e+i++-6),main(i);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pcs9DsIwDEDhq6BONm4QMHRJ2osghshyqCNIq7RMVY/dOfwIsT69j82NuRTufd5LW4HrDq7Dyj68JtA64qIB1DW4hCED0Tu1Rxud2vE5fxTIJRJdEX8E7Sr3SXZfdjrjmDXNAYSUyDRY/69StjQY9tzLCw)

Comment: Please also share your none-hardcoded solution. Despite being longer I'm sure it's much more interesting than this trivial one.

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica 41 bytes

```
""<>"(<>.<>)"~StringDrop~i~Table~{i,-5,5}
```

Answer (score 2):

### **[q](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/card/), 29 bytes**

`raze"(<>.<>)"{(y-5)_x}/:(!)11`

*-2 bytes thanks to streetster*

EDIT for explanation:

Language is right to left interpreted.

**How it works**

```
raze"(<>.<>)"{(y-5)_x}/:(!)11
                        (!)11 /yields indices [0-10], right parameter of function (y)
                      /:      /each right: loop right parameter of a dyadic function
             {       }        /function
    "(<>.<>)"                 /left parameter of function (x)
              (y-5)           /subtract 5 from y (indices)
                   _          /remove first y chars from x, or last y chars if negative
raze                          /flatten string output to produce the final string
```

Comment: An explanation here would be great.

Comment: You can remove the space before the `_x` for 1 byte, and change `til 11` to `(!)11` for another 1 byte saving = 2 bytes saved :)

Comment: @streetster great stuff :)

Answer (score 2):

A crowd of blank stares watching Batman [in honor of Adam West](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/126223/70347)...

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 393 bytes

```cs
s=>{string b="NanananaNanaBATMAN!NanaBATMAN!NANANanaBATMAN!NANAnanaNanaBATMAN!NANABATMAN!NanaBATMAN!NANABATMAN!naNABATMAN!NANABATMAN!naNANAnaNANABATMAN!naNANANABATMAN!naNABATMAN!naNANAnanaNA",r="",t;for(int i=0;i<176;)if(b[i]=='B'){r+="<>";i+=7;}else{t=b.Substring(i,4);if(t=="Nana")r+="(";else if(t=="nana")r+="<";else if(t=="NAna")r+=">";else if(t=="NANA")r+=".";else r+=")";i+=4;}return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVFPa4MwFL/7Kd5yaUKdbFDWQ4xgB7u1DDroYewQbSwBjZDEwRA/u0vUubXzPch7@f0JL0lu7vNaix5c5CU3Bl51fdG8CjzSDqsPY7mVOXzW8gx7LhUmM/Ur8nH8MlZU0Uuj8thYLdUlhLEmUAALesOSdgQgY@jA1ZC@7tK3fXq4@9umLq@3t2IHLfum1qnTZdSf9Q9a8v2IfUWhZgiFlha1xlJZkOyByvhx@0SJLHD2Lj8YW@1WpNVrhuIEUblmW9qJ0ojWsiw6Ntl4eyzDDaHOY9n4DIh4C0bUa2Ei1EzE14QfaCSSW8JNORDRRPieDINsaKeFbbQCTbueBks/91wrU5ciOmlpBS4wSs@8gpMwFhFCZ0c3dF3/DQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>55</s> 45 bytes

```hs
map take[2..7]++map drop[1..5]>>=($"(<>.<>)")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzPzexQKEkMTs12khPzzxWWxvETynKL4g21NMzjbWzs9VQUdKwsdOzsdNU0gSqzsyzLSgtCS4pUkn7/y85LScxvfi/boRzQAAA)

First Haskell answer to beat the hardcoded solution!

### Explanation

The way this answer works is by building a list of functions to be applied to the string `(<>.<>)`.  First we build the left and center with

```hs
map take[2..7]
```

which gives us all the prefixes from size two to seven.  Then we build the right with

```hs
map drop[1..5]
```

which gives us all the suffixes from size six to two.

Once we have the list of functions we use a monadic bind (`>>=`) which is just `concatMap` but shorter.  The function we concatmap with is `($"(<>.<>)")` which applies the input to the string `(<>.<>)`.

This makes the string.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 22 bytes

1 byte thanks to Kritixi Lithos.

```
U;\UṚṖ
“(<>.<>)”;\ḊṖ,Ç
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/UOib04c5ZD3dO43rUMEfDxk7Pxk7zUcNc65iHO7qAojqH2///BwA)

Comment: I think you can drop the `µ`

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 52 bytes

```
x->"(<(<>(<>.(<>.<(<>.<>(<>.<>)<>.<>)>.<>).<>)<>)>)"
```

Boring, but there isn't any way to make this shorter in Java.. Just initializing a temp String is already 11 bytes.. (`String t="something";`), and using `substring` a couple of times certainly costs too many bytes..

Shortest alternative to a literal return is probably this (58 bytes):

```
x->"(<(x(x.(x.<(x.x(x.x)x.x)>.x).x)x)>)".replace("x","<>")
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##LY5BDoMgEEX3PcXEFSzkAlpuULvosukCkTZYRAODsTGenaKYzLzkzyQ/rxezKMdJ2b77RmmE93AT2q4XAG1RubeQCpo9AjzQafsBSe5tryTCQqt03y4JHgVqCQ1YuEJcSr46hcHZgtSk5mnYvvUBnkkzD@RIOS2qLVZ74RRakwrP3nnUHQzJi2SH5wsEPaV@HtXAxoBsSi8klkligzH0tNviHw)

Comment: Also works in JavaScript, using a "fat arrow" function (`=>`) if you want to add it.

Comment: @Shaggy Nah, you can keep your JavaScript answer if you want. The same applies to C# which also already has a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, 57 bytes

```
print''.join("(<>.<>)"[max(0,n-5):n+2]for n in range(11))
```

I say it looks like a gang of owls peeking out behind their leader. Just saying.

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 28 bytes

```
'(<>.<>)'XH5:"H7@-:)wh2M@+)h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X13Dxk7Pxk5TPcLD1ErJw9xB10qzPMPI10FbM@P/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 95 bytes

```
import Data.List
import Control.Arrow
concat$tail$init$uncurry(++)$inits&&&tail.tails$"(<>.<>)"
```

This is far longer than the 49 bytes necessary for a string literal with the output, but the best I could do to utilise [the structure](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/127428/a-crowd-of-blank-stares#comment314011_127428). As usual, I love arrows, and `inits &&& tails` does produce a tuple of the list of leading substrings and the list of trailing substrings of the input. Then those two tuple elements are put together in one list by passing the tuple to `++`, and that list is `concat`enated to one large string. The `tail` and `init` calls avoid duplicating the `(<>.<>)` in the middle (one generated by `inits`, the other by `tails`) and drop the unwanted parenthesis from the start and end, taking only substrings of length 2 or more into account.

Comment: Can you please add an explanation?

Comment: @CalculatorFeline Done

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tio-transpilers), <s>245</s> 210 bytes

Golfing in progress.

```
>++++++++[<+++++>-]>++++++[<++++++++++>-]>++++++[<++++++++++>-]<++>>++++++++[<+++++>-]<++++++<<<.>.<.>.>.<<.>.>.>.<<<.>.>.>.<<.<.>.>.>.<<.>.<<.>.>.>.<<.>.<<+.>.>.>.<<.>.<<.>>.>.<<.>.<<.>>>.<<.>.<<.>.>.<<.>>.<<.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v/fThsKom3AlJ1urB2KAH5RIM8OixFQRTY2Nnp2eiAMJCEUiIFg6SExUZSACW10SVQOqi6IPJD8/x8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 bytes

```
“(<>.<>)”ḣJœ|ṫJ$ḊṖ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9qZWxsef//4oCcKDw@Ljw@KeKAneG4o0rFk3zhuatKJOG4iuG5lv//)

#### How it works

```
“(<>.<>)”ḣJœ|ṫJ$ḊṖ  Main link. No arguments.

“(<>.<>)”           Set the argument and return value to s := "(<>.<>)".
          J         Yield all indices of s, i.e., [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].
         ḣ          Dyadic head; yield s's prefixes of lengths 1 to 7.
               $    Combine the two links to the left into a chain.
              J         Indices; yield [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].
             ṫ          Dyadic tail; yield s's postfixes of lengths 1 to 7.
           œ|       Multiset union; concatenate the results to both sides,
                    discarding the copy of s. (s is both a prefix and a postfix.)
                Ḋ   Dequeue; remove the first prefix, i.e., "(".
                 Ṗ  Pop; remove the last postfix, i.e., ")".
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>62</s> 61 bytes

```c
main(n){while(write(++n<13,n/7*(n-7)+"(<>.<>)",n/7?14-n:n));}
```

This terminates only after timing out on TIO because the write to standard *input* fails, but it *will* terminate in a terminal. The program relies on a specific order of evaluation (undefined behavior) and won't work with, e.g., gcc.

*Thanks to @Steadybox for an idea that saved a byte!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///PzcxM08jT7O6PCMzJ1WjvCizJFVDWzvPxtBYJ0/fXEsjT9dcU1tJw8ZOz8ZOUwkkZm9ooptnlaepaV37/z8A)

#### Verification

```c
$ cat crowd.c
main(n){while(write(++n<12,n/7*(n-7)+"(<>.<>)",n/7?14-n:n));}
$ clang -o crowd crowd.c 2> /dev/null

$ ./crowd 0> /dev/null
(<(<>(<>.(<>.<(<>.<>(<>.<>)<>.<>)>.<>).<>)<>)
```

### Alternate version, 62 bytes

```c
main(n){while(++n<13)write(1,n/7*(n-7)+"(<>.<>)",n/7?14-n:n);}
```

At the cost of one more byte, the solution becomes a lot more portable.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///PzcxM08jT7O6PCMzJ1VDWzvPxtBYs7wosyRVw1AnT99cSyNP11xTW0nDxk7Pxk5TCSRmb2iim2eVp2ld@/8/AA)

Comment: [60 bytes as a function](https://tio.run/##fchBCsIwEAXQfU5RspoxjRIUCk6oZwmh0YD@lpriovTYrqNewLd80cZ7wLXWROA1jTOJM685l4GMgXfHFoduR7AdG02@3/ue9e8u7mRxBgvLVjNK8wgZxGpVzVcilmkpT9Ka5c@orb4x2hjibfgA), but it's probably not reliable.

Comment: Nice!  [58 bytes with recursion](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@zWls7T9/MprwosyRVw1AnT99cSyNP11xTW0nDxk7Pxk5TCSRmb2iim2eVp6mmBtJjXfs/M69EITcxM09Dk6uaSwEI0jQ0rQtKS4o1lJQ0rfGIcNX@/5qXr5ucmJyRCgA), but [it breaks if the program is called with arguments](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///P00jT7NaWztP38ymvCizJFXDUCdP31xLI0/XXFNbScPGTs/GTlMJJGZvaKKbZ5WnqaYG0mNd@z8zr0QhNzEzT0OTq5pLAQjSNDStuWr///@al6@bnJickQoA).

Comment: @Dennis Yeah, the `(<` is missing there.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 55 bytes

couldn't resist beating the [current python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127525/76162)

```python
print "(<(<>(<>.(<>.<(<>.<>(<>.<>)<>.<>)>.<>).<>)<>)>)"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qvrGGjYWMHRHogbAMm7CCkJoQEExCupp3m/4KizLwSBSUStSn9/w8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 19 bytes

```
“(<>.<>)”µṖ¹Ƥ;¹ÐƤṖḊ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/9qZWxsef//4oCcKDw@Ljw@KeKAncK14bmWwrnGpDvCucOQxqThuZbhuIr//w)

Answer (score 1):

## J, <s>30</s> <s>25</s> 24 Bytes

```
;}.}:~.(<\,<\.)'(<>.<>)'
```

Explanation later, I have a feeling I can golf this more...

#### Edit:

-<s>5</s> 6 Bytes thanks to @FrownyFrog :)

#### Explanation:

```
               '(<>.<>)'   | The face
       (   <\.)            | Apply box to the suffixes of '(<>.<>)': Gives '(<>.<>)', '<>.<>)' ... ')'
          ,                | Append to...
        <\                 | Box applied to the prefixes of '(<>.<>)'
 }.}:~.                    | Remove the extra '(<>.<>)', as well as '(' and ')' from the front and back
;                          | Join into one string
```

Comment: @FrownyFrog ...maybe.... :P

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>16</s> 14 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ü■_'σIHa¬ø·hÑè
```

[Run and debug it at staxlang.xyz!](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=81fe5f27e5494861aa00fa68a58a&i=&a=1)

#### Unpacked (16 bytes) and explanation:

```
"(<>.":w|[D$3T:w
"(<>."              String literal                     (<>.
      :w            Palindromize, flipping (){}[]<>    (<>.<>)
        |[          Array of prefixes                  [ ( (< .. (<>.<>) ]
          D         Drop first                         [ (< (<> .. (<>.<>) ]
           $        Concatenate                        (<(<>(<>.(<>.<(<>.<>(<>.<>)
            3T      Drop last three                    (<(<>(<>.(<>.<(<>.<>(<>.
              :w    Palindromize, flipping (){}[]<>
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 54 bytes

```python
f=lambda i=5:L*0**i or L[:-i]+f(i-1)+L[i:]
L='(<>.<>)'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIdPW1MpHy0BLK1Mhv0jBJ9pKNzNWO00jU9dQU9snOtMqlsvHVl3Dxk7Pxk5T/X9BUWZeiUaahqbmfwA)

Slight improvement on the [leading Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/154036/87681)

Port of my [Lenny's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/190121/87681)

Answer (score 1):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 278 bytes

```
{iiii}c{ii}c{dd}c{ii}ciic{dd}ddc{ii}ciic{d}ddddddcddddddc{ii}ciic{d}ddddddc{i}iiiic{dd}c{ii}ciic{d}ddddddc{i}iiiiciic{dd}ddc{ii}ciic{d}ddddddc{i}iiiiciic{dd}dc{ii}dciic{d}ddddddc{i}iiiiciic{dd}dc{ii}ic{d}ddddddc{i}iiiiciic{dd}dciiiiic{i}iiiiciic{dd}dc{ii}dciic{dd}dc{ii}ic{dd}dc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0lNTEnLLM7Q/f@/OhMIapOrwURKCpSVmQnmpKQgcYE8EEiGUpgS1Zm1IMPQjUGXxmc2uhqwkhQi1OBVkAlxFh6zkY0Bsf//BwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 39 bytes

```
(<(a(a.(a.<(a.a(abab>bba)>)
b
.a)
a
<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fS8NGI1EjUQ@IgAw9IDMpMckuKSlR006TK4lLL1GTK5HLxu7/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 104 bytes

```
string a="(<>.<>)",s="";for(int i=2,k=a.Length;i<k*2-1;i++){s+=(k>i)?a.Substring(0,i):a.Substring(i-k);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYyxCsIwFEV3vyJkSmwb1NE2dXCtIHRwjjHWR9oE8qIgpd8eq4J4hjPcA1djoX0wieheIZJj8F1Qw4LMjB@/wagiaPLwcCEHBY7xXxoTxgCuI0pSVtWiqjnNUVJaXn1g4CIBucmtVKIxrou3Eiq73BTrErKMj5hJZmvgOyXa@/n7xFY58O3/AIXl5ZTaJ0YziL136HsjTgGiacAZhnOd0gs)

Comment: `t.Text`? Do you perhaps mean another variable?

Comment: I think it would be shorter to... just do the entire string.

Comment: @LiefdeWen done

Comment: @LeakyNun Yeah C# doesn't fare well at all at most kolmogorov complexity questions

Comment: @LeakyNun just trying to give tips

Comment: @ErlantzCalvo instead of `var a="...";var s=""` do `string a="...",s=""` on 2 declarations it saves you 1 byte and on more declarations more bytes

Comment: @ErlantzCalvo instead of `i<=a.Length` do `a.Length>i`

Comment: @LiefdeWen edited, thanks!

Comment: you use a.Length three times so you can do in the `for` loop declaration: `int i=2,k=a.Length` and use `k` in the loop instead of `a.Length`

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 52 bytes

Obvious solution; doesn't seem to be much room for any trickery here.

```js
f=

_=>"(<(<>(<>.(<>.<(<>.<>(<>.<>)<>.<>)>.<>).<>)<>)>)"

o.innerText=f()
```

```html
<pre id=o>
```

Comment: [I did some trickery!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127455/48878)

Comment: @Artyer, so I saw, nicely done :)

Answer (score 0):

## Brainfuck, 489 bytes

```
++[------>+<]>---.[-->+++<]>.[--->++<]>.[-->+++<]>.++.--[--->++<]>.[-->+++<]>.++.[->+++++++++<]>.------.[-->+++<]>.++.[->+++++++++<]>.--[----->+<]>.[--->++<]>.[-->+++<]>.++.[->+++++++++<]>.--[----->+<]>.++.--[--->++<]>.[-->+++<]>.++.[->+++++++++<]>.--[----->+<]>.++.+[--->++<]>-.-[-->+++<]>.++.[->+++++++++<]>.--[----->+<]>.++.+[--->++<]>-.+[-->+++<]>-.[->+++++++++<]>.--[----->+<]>.++.+[--->++<]>-.+++++.--[----->+<]>.++.+[--->++<]>-.-[-->+++<]>.++.+[--->++<]>-.+[-->+++<]>-.+[--->++<]>-.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>41</s> 25 bytes

```
"(<>.<>)"
¤£¯Ò°TÃ+U+¤£s°V
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=Iig8Pi48PikiCqSjr9KwVMMrVSuko3OwVg==&input=)

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL, 54 bytes (the trivial solution)

```sql
PRINT'(<(<>(<>.(<>.<(<>.<>(<>.<>)<>.<>)>.<>).<>)<>)>)'
```

I like this challenge, simple and yet so annoying.

I tried hard to find alternates, but nothing was shorter, due mostly due to the length of SQL keywords. Hmm, maybe I need to create GolfSQL with minimized keywords and other optimizations...

Here's my best attempt at a procedural solution (97 bytes golfed, presented here formatted):

```sql
DECLARE @ INT=-4, @o VARCHAR(99)=''
a:
    SET @o+=SUBSTRING('(<>.<>)',@,7)
    SET @+=1
IF @<7 GOTO a
PRINT @o
```

This works because `SUBSTRING` can take a negative start value, in which case it simply reduces the length.

**Edit**: Found a slightly shorter non-trivial solution (96 bytes):

```sql
SELECT STRING_AGG(SUBSTRING('(<>.<>)',number-4,7),'')FROM
spt_values WHERE TYPE='P'AND number<11
```

Only works on MS SQL Server, where the `master` database has a built-in system table called `spt_values`. This table (when filtered by `WHERE TYPE='P'`) can be used as a number table to generate the values from -4 to 6.

Answer (score 0):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), 24 bytes

```
0000000: d3 b0 d1 b0 b1 03 22 3d 10 b6 01 13 76 10 52 13  ......"=....v.R.
0000010: 42 82 09 10 06 b1 35 01                          B.....5.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYy7DYAwEEN7prAYILoPCR@JhhEY4RREAyWsH7hQ8wrLlqxnl9mx7ddZCn1MyAojZPY0BilEoBn8zgRisKJPPqN4R6i0s@cd1tBUEb@qTjAIaPQzJbdpdMMvS1XFUMoD)

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 29 bytes

```
K"(<>.<>)"s++m<KhdS5Km>hdK_S5
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=K%22%28%3C%3E.%3C%3E%29%22s%2B%2Bm%3CKhdS5Km%3EhdK_S5&debug=0)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 75+1(-w) = 76 bytes

I'm unsure of how needed -w is, but it wasn't printing the output until I tried it.

```perl
for(-5..5){$l=-abs($_)+7;$o=$_>0?7-$l:0;$s.=substr"(<>.<>)",$o,$l;}print$s;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFNCoMwEAbQu4RvkVAT3ASh@fEoomBBCE7IpHRRvLrje3VvxYt8qGnrnfPmj5LsurHGYl5TACUseZwni/IeA9gl/m7cm9Ixu5iNGkADSrhqO84ODiI31X7QyWJ/Dw)

Ungolfed

```perl
for(-5..5){
  $l = -abs($_) + 7;
  $o = $_ > 0 ? 7 - $l : 0;
  $s .= substr "(<>.<>)", $o, $l;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Matlab, <strike>74</strike> <strike>68</strike> 65 bytes

```
function[m]=f,s='(<>.<>)';m=s;for i=2:6,m=[s(1:8-i),m,s(i:7)];end
```

Runs perfectly on Matlab and prints: `(<(<>(<>.(<>.<(<>.<>(<>.<>)<>.<>)>.<>).<>)<>)>)`. However, it prints on Octave. So the link is useless.

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAr3RzBQvqUKGuHxEPYQp7UKG1vm8zLfbrS2Pkt8ZOrfoSMCtGAdYt1klhCrLJ7ZkIN72rgp5h1edMUhXFQPqQwaR6jwxy/A)

Answer (score 0):

## Julia, 60 bytes

```
prod([("(<>.<>)"^2)[min(x,8):max(x,7)] for x in[9:13;1:6]])
```

Comment: I think there is a superfluous space in `] for`

Comment: @JonathanFrech This is new, in Julia 1.0 it is needed. Julia had some potential but really seems to lack commitment to become a serious golfing language.

Comment: I do not know a lot about Julia, but [TIO's Julia](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUz8X1CUmVeiAaTyUzSiNZQ0bOz0bOw0leKMNKNzM/M0KnQsNK1yEyuADHPN2LT8IoUKhcy8aEsrQ2NrQyuz2FjN/5r/AQ) seems to be on version 0.4; the space does not appear necessary there.

Answer (score -2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 47 bytes

Needs a file with the Content-Type `text/plain`

```php
(<(<>(<>.(<>.<(<>.<>(<>.<>)<>.<>)>.<>).<>)<>)>)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P9fw0bDxg6I9EDYBkzYQUhNCAkmIFxNO83//wE)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 53 bytes

```php
<?="(<(<>(<>.(<>.<(<>.<>(<>.<>)<>.<>)>.<>).<>)<>)>)";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt5WScNGw8YOiPRA2AZM2EFITQgJJiBcTTtNJev//wE)

Comment: The first one is also a valid `echo` program.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline No in the first example the PHP interpreter prints only the text. There is no start tag.  We must avoid to do this in a html file.

Comment: ...Confused. Where did I mention HTML?

Comment: @CalculatorFeline Nowhere! You can not use echo in the first case

Comment: I suppose the correct language is `cat`.