# Tribute to Stan Lee

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

Unfortunately [one of the greatest comic book writers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stan_Lee) passed away yesterday afternoon. Lots of Hollywood stars, musicians, actors, and many other people are paying tribute to this awesome writer, so we must do something as well.

**Challenge**

Print The Avengers Logo

Note: You may use any other character in place of # other than a space character; while you must use a space character for the space

[image]

In ASCII-art

```
              ######       
      ###############      
    #####    ##########    
  ####       ####### ####  
 ###        #### ###   ### 
###         #### ###    ###
###        ####  ###    ###
###        ####  ###    ###
###       ####   ###    ###
###       ####   ###    ###
###      ###########    ###
###      ###########    ###
###     ####     ###    ###
###     ###      ###    ###
 ####  ####           #### 
  ########         ######  
      #################    
      ###
```

**Optional**

Who was (in your opinion) his greatest hero and villain in the entire marvel universe?

---

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply

Comment: What happened to the → in Ⓐ?

Comment: @Adám 2 Reasons. I believe that the arrow means the continuation of the series (in this case the comics about avengers). Since Stan passed away there wont be a continuation of it (In my opinion, it is not the same without Stan). That is one of the reasons

Comment: The second one is that I didnt know how to draw it :c

Comment: Are the trailing spaces required?

Comment: @Scoots no, it is not required as long as your output looks the same

Comment: Lmao, no one answered your essay question, not even in passing. This is peak codegolf.SE.

Answer (score 26):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>62</s> <s>59</s> 58 bytes

```
“ḢE{ɠs{Ƒ0Ṇṁỵ8ỊṢṂƊeLṫfIWẈḞ'ʠJ£ṗɱ\çoȧ?ƒnØẆƥṂ⁷ɱ’b12ĖŒṙḂa⁶s27Y
```

*Thanks to @JonathanAllan for golfing off 1 byte!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AXcAiP9qZWxsef//4oCc4biiRXvJoHN7xpEw4bmG4bmB4bu1OOG7iuG5ouG5gsaKZUzhuatmSVfhuojhuJ4nyqBKwqPhuZfJsVzDp2/Ipz/Gkm7DmOG6hsal4bmC4oG3ybHigJliMTLElsWS4bmZ4biCYeKBtnMyN1n//w)

#### How it works

```
“ḢE{ɠs{Ƒ0Ṇṁỵ8ỊṢṂƊeLṫfIWẈḞ'ʠJ£ṗɱ\çoȧ?ƒnØẆƥṂ⁷ɱ’
```

is a bijective base-250 integer literal, which uses the characters in [Jelly's code page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page) as digits.

The literal encodes the integer \$\scriptsize 10250938842396786963034911279002199266186481794751691439873548591280332406943905758890346943197901909163\$, which `b12` converts to duodecimal, yielding \$\scriptsize 30b620b40ba54a64771433841333139413468423468423467433467433466b466b465453465363431424b43896860ba3_{12}\$.

There are some zeroes, because 14 spaces (e.g.) are encoded as 3 spaces, 0 hashes, and 11 spaces. This maintains the base small (the largest run consists of 17 hashes), without adding any additional logic to the decoder.

`Ė` (enumerate) prefixes every base-12 digit by its 1-based index, then `Œṙ` performs run-length decoding.

Now, for each integer in the resulting array, `Ḃ` extracts the least significant bit, then `a⁶` (AND space) replaces ones with spaces, while leaving zeroes unchanged.

Finally, `s27` splits the unformatted character array into chunks of length 27, which `Y` separates by linefeeds.

Answer (score 18):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>198</s>, <s>173</s>, <s>163</s>, <s>157</s>, <s>144</s>, 142 bytes

```r
write(rep(rep(c(' ',4),44),utf8ToInt("NFMOJEDJFDGGADCCHDACCCACIDACDFHDBCDFHDBCDFGDCCDFGDCCDFFKDFFKDFEDECDFECFCDCADBDKDCHIFHQJC")-64),1,27,,'')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY1LCgIxEESvIrNJAu1CGdRtpiudz6AieAOZATcqIeLxY1B08V5R1KJyra98LZPO0@PDRauFot5Q33iWeXe@x1vR3UH2x@SQBN5bMAdYZrYcW0IChr99W3@W8YuDa82xMNhiwAgOUcIpcWeWm/a0ovWWSClT6xs)

Also `R` honors to the great Stan.

**Notes :**

- instead of the character `#` we've used the character `4` because saves 2 bytes and :

  - it's a reference to the Fantastic Four and/or the next Avengers 4 movie
  - it's like we're repeating the logo inside the logo (since `4` seems a mini "slanted" `A`)
- -15 bytes thanks to @Giuseppe

**Explanation** :

Applying a Run Length Encoding (`rle` function) on the characters of the string (excluding `'\n'`) returns 88 repetitions of the alternating `<space>,<hash>,<space>,<hash>,<space>,<hash>...`.

The 88 repetitions are all values in the range `[1,17]` hence, summing `64` we get the code points of the letters `[A...Q]` obtaining the string : `"NFMOJEDJFDGGADCCHDACCCACIDACDFHDBCDFHDBCDFGDCCDFGDCCDFFKDFFKDFEDECDFECFCDCADBDKDCHIFHQJC"`

Hence the code basically does the opposite operations :

```r
v <- utf8ToInt("NFMOJEDJFDGGADC...")-64  # convert the string back to [1...17] vector

e <- rep(rep(c(' ',4),44),v)             # perform the inverse of rle function obtaining an
                                         # expanded vector of <space>'s and <four>'s

write(e,1,27,,'')                        # write the vector to stdout arranging it 
                                         # in rows of maximum 27 characters
```

Comment: Your solution is nicer, but your own gzip 2-parter gives 89+47 = [136 bytes](https://tio.run/##lZHPasMwDMbvfgphDxQH08NO26CXbY/QYy9qo26Gxgm2Q9lePnOavw09rMJg6/th@bPkW9oi3IS6xpCIpTbFgk35LRW9cFNSDZKAmcCo90cQC7Rk3SbW1x5nan7pEbb6@n@ZWhzuMFiz2blazWPsp1q3p@/nvRlNcxgYCnHxNvK7dVnJ5UdV1p5DyEgbJNRCHClmMs9z2H3bAGkRPMPJnhlCcyhtCLZymwQZqChsTBmd4fATOUDRMMQKrKub2F9xVHIBqTCQZ3gDaa76xrpTlUmS@inYXzaAQ4X0Lhrcu71DE7jeSqnbzlBy@snH0atnKjr/qa5BTxc0L6/J/heandZt@wc "R – Try It Online").

Comment: @J.Doe : ahah I even forgot to have used that approach! please post it as your own answer :)

Comment: Since we can use any character for `#`, using `0` in place of `"#"` should save 2 more bytes. @J.Doe that may work better for your gzip as well.

Answer (score 13):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), <s>71</s> <s>66</s> <s>65</s> 64 bytes

```
0000000: 95 91 21 12 00 20 08 c0 3a af 90 ff 7f 52 4e 58  ..!.. ..:....RNX
0000010: 58 93 25 d8 8a 27 47 e4 23 66 01 2c ce b1 3c 12  X.%..'G.#f.,..<.
0000020: 5f 5b 17 7c 81 ed 31 28 4e 6e a4 6d 23 ad 5b c2  _[.|..1(Nn.m#.[.
0000030: ae 25 83 9a 94 1a 2f 6f 05 fc e5 f0 73 13 f9 0b  .%..../o....s...
```

*Thanks to @ovs for golfing off 1 byte!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc@7ToMxDAXgnac4C0zIcm5Owlgx8BYQ54IQhQW1Cw//49JWrJzBzpJPx3pQ3c/Xw8e28SUPqKk6qOMBZs/g0hlZ2kTg6bCWW/ApeoBOsXkktsft7uYsODNKlonhuWK0ntCLs5@VC5yYVmYO8L0sMz7pL1/3dDG8GT2OjCGckJZYBeWO0mqAUzFXY8HUKucezy/fp/VGT3Q1ghnKoui1Mbw06yFdIdVOyytUrD46YlzTjHeiu1@AKtHj1YhmsJ36r9C2/QA)

Comment: How exactly do you golf bytes off of Bubblegum? I assumed the strategy would be to try each compression algorithm and pick the one that compresses your input the most. Where do you go from there?

Comment: @Cowabunghole The first golf removed the trailing spaces, the second one increased the number of zopfli iterations (ovs's idea), and the last one switched from `#` to `!`.

Answer (score 12):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>244</s> <s>243</s> 242 bytes

```c
#define z <<10|117441415
x[]={8064,2097088,8142832,31473596,58751886,30 z,60 z,60 z,120 z,120 z,255 z,255 z,480 z,448 z,63897630,33423612,2097136,1835008};b(_,i){i&&b(_/2,i-1),putchar(32+_%2*3);}main(_){_<19&&b(x[_-1],27)&puts("")&main(_+1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc3dasJAEIbhc68iWAxZndCdn92dYLwSkUWjtnugFG1BjF57TCroycvH8MA05VfTdN3HdrdPx112zeoa7Q0xiKCgG12Wq0Wr1guQrYJVBUUhZQJGCewqD06DQ1UPbLMr@FeQ3iXnXhUdLiI6QNYqeLbALMQe6f8NsgdUdtbqfb4pIiTTpjzv1ydBKtHAz99v870@FUyzOKEpm/n9sE7HIpo21lgN9rKMJa6Agsl7fS7GY5M/zQx73nUP)

-1 Thanks to Peter Cordes

-1 Thanks to ceilingcat

Uses bit compression.

#### Explanation:

The goal is to print a set of numbers in binary using space and # as digits which represent the logo. A bit of bash magic converts the logo to binary masks:

```c
echo "ibase=2;$(<code which echoes the logo [see my bash solution for example]> | tr ' #' 01)" | bc
```

This results in the binary 'numbers' being:

```c
8064,2097088,8142832,31473596,58751886,117472135,117502855,117502855,117564295,117564295,117702535,117702535,117932935,117900167,63897630,33423612,2097136,1835008
```

There is an obvious pattern in the middle where every line contains `###              ###     ###`

We can save some space by compressing that middle section based on saving that pattern and OR-ing against it. In addition, all of those lines merely add some stuff to the left of the middle section, so we make the `z` macro which takes `??????????????` and converts it into `###??????????????###     ###`. This involves bitshifting left by 10 and OR-ing with the binary of that pattern, which is 117441415.

Now we can more easily understand the code:

```c
#define z <<10|117441415 // Define z to be the compression defined above
x[]={                    // Define x to be an array storing each line's number
8064,2097088,8142832,    // The first 5 lines are uncompressed
31473596,58751886,
30 z,60 z,60 z,120 z,    // The middle 9 lines are z-compressed
120 z,255 z,255 z,480 z,
448 z,
63897630,33423612,       // The last 4 lines are uncompressed
2097136,1835008};
b(_,i){                  // we also need a function to print n-bit binary numbers
i&&                      // i is the bit counter, we recurse until its zero
b(_/2,i-1),              // each recursive call halves the input and decrements i
putchar(" #"[_%2]);}     // this just prints the correct character
main(_){                 // this is the main function, called as ./? will have 1 in _ (argc)
_<19?                    // if _ is less than 19 then...
  b(x[_-1],27),          // print the binary expansion of x[_-1]
  puts(""),              // print a new line
  main(_+1)              // recurse with _++
:0;}
```

Comment: Can `x?y:0` be replaced with `x&&y`, or does  operator precedence not work?  Maybe with `&` instead of `,` separating the 3 function calls because `&` has higher precedence than `&&` or `,` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).  Or not because only `,` provides a sequence point for the printing vs. recursion to avoid undefined behaviour.

Comment: It doesn't work with `&&` indeed because of the precedence, while `&` doesn't short-circuit. As of yet I haven't found a shorter alternative, though I wouldn't rule one out.

Comment: I meant with `&` or `|` or `^` replacing `,` (*because* they don't short-circuit) and `&&` replacing `?` (because it does).  Like `_<19 && b() & puts() & main(_+1);` (spaces added for readability).  The order of evaluation is undefined, which may actually undefined behaviour because of unsequenced side-effects on `stdout` https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order, but in practice any given compiler will pick some order for a given set of target + options.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean. You're right - that does work! -1 byte.

Comment: You don't need the space between the macro and the definition.

Comment: [241 bytes](https://tio.run/##Rc3disIwEIbh870KUSzNOsXMT5Ip1isRCW7V3RysiD8gVq@9tgp68vIxPDB18VvXbTtab7ZptxlcqwrtDTGIoKD7uiyW80atFyBbBqsKikLKBIwS2JUenAaHqh7YDq7g30H6lJx7V7S/iGgPWcvg2QKzEHuk5xtkD6jsrNX77CePkEyTsqxbU4JUoIH9@VT/rQ450ySO6ZvN7P6/Srs8miZWWPb2sogFLoGCyTp9zIdDk73MBDvetg8)

Comment: Building on @Zacharý [239 bytes](https://tio.run/##RY3baoNAFEXf8xWSUnHqkc65zMyRmC@RMCTGtvPQUHqBEOu3W/UhfVlsNmuzu@q166bp4dy/pEuf3ZoG7S9iEEFBt4lwbQ/7Qa0XIFsHqwqKQsoEjBLY1R6cBoeqHthmN/B3IP2TnLtTdGlEdBFZ6@DZArMQe6T1BtkDKjtrddydigjJDCnP5/RMkCo08PHz3b0dPwumMj7SE5vd@H5Ml8IMsUFd1GsbD0DB5Gsfy/08@Sq2WzOr0/QH "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 12):

## Python 2, 129 bytes

```bash
00000000: 2363 6f64 696e 673a 4c31 0a70 7269 6e74  #coding:L1.print
00000010: 2778 da95 9141 0e5c 3021 0803 ef7d 4593  'x...A.\0!...}E.
00000020: feff 8f9b 5d14 5c6e f1b0 f622 7422 2890  ....].\n..."t"(.
00000030: 2e7d 5a09 dc4b 19cb bc53 84d1 4a6a 5960  .}Z..K...S..JjY`
00000040: 116e 3f42 c290 b3f7 c0bc 76cf 549d 6ed8  .n?B......v.T.n.
00000050: f8fa 5f26 0b0e 8c93 d5cb 35f6 b1e7 a939  .._&......5....9
00000060: 9e98 e769 47b9 87d6 cdf5 5c30 3030 32c0  ...iG.....\0002.
00000070: 4029 272e 6465 636f 6465 2827 7a69 7027  @)'.decode('zip'
00000080: 29                                       )
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZE7b1RBDIV7fsUhSGxSZDRPzzgNDwkhAV1oQBuFOy@yFDersEILIr998WTv9riw3fjz8XGeft4dDvt9xeUD/mL7e3d3P1tcHg56iStYRw7UyYOYGii6Cb44Az1FjWiJQS164EW5r5v5@9Uno7YPm3n37EgwgxFjQp04gI2XyRYKnLbSJe3QeqzwgR2w2iul3qi1fi718Z1aGFYYvfWO1DkjVOMRiojpJmt0shbRS7KJNSCT6katZylnu7PzE8MNHU02hUkzavEZhktGLsEh@WrgJ5oQmAbj8atSH4VwrdSHH1@@LQwvDGNkseveolhZl12PKDoXRCodwXMVP2oSxvzqrXqKX@qzmk86wrglddnULUFn3ZCK3F6DiHGhE7JpERM7Hrfcvjwywki8MEgY3DihRbHfx8xIsRJK7UGccVrcHcmWox@b90@M9bDypCMKw2vL8hwrb/UUQI76sbPJRsRJ4FFLh9cXK1WbPLidr/5stquFkYanIvO/4uIf)

Comment: [129 bytes](https://tio.run/##jZE7b1RBDIV7fsUhSGxSZDRPzzgNDwkhAV1oQBuFOy@yFDersEILIr998WTv9riw3fjz8XGeft4dDvt9xeUD/mL7e3d3P1tcHg56iStYRw7UyYOYGii6Cb44Az1FjWiJQS164EW5r5v5@9Uno7YPm3n37EgwgxFjQp04gI2XyRYKnLbSJe3QeqzwgR2w2iul3qi1fi718Z1aGFYYvfWO1DkjVOMRiojpJmt0shbRS7KJNSCT6katZylnu7PzE8MNHU02hUkzavEZhktGLsEh@WrgJ5oQmAbj8atSH4VwrdSHH1@@LQwvDGNkseveolhZl12PKDoXRCodwXMVP2oSxvzqrXqKX@qzmk86wrglddnULUFn3ZCK3F6DiHGhE7JpERM7Hrfcvjwywki8MEgY3DihRbHfx8xIsRJK7UGccVrcHcmWox@b90@M9bDypCMKw2vL8hwrb/UUQI76sbPJRsRJ4FFLh9cXK1WbPLidr/5stquFkYanIvO/4uIf), I removed the trailing `\n` from the compressed string.

Answer (score 12):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>71</s> <s>68</s> 67 bytes

```
←⁸↙Ｐ⁵↘←⁴↓Ｐ³↙Ｆ⁹⟦³⟧→Ｐ⁴↘Ｐ⁶↘‖ＯＭ←←¹⁷↘Ｆ⁹«Ｐ⁺³›ι³↑Ｐ⁴↗¿⁼ι²Ｂ⁸±²»↘→ＵＯ³¦¹⁴ＵＭＫＡ#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBNT8MwDIbP3a@IxsWRymHrgH2c@BIXYNUkTohDVtwuwmtKlhYkxG8PS0erRsotsh8/ee1sJ3SmBFmbalkaWD5ibmI256vRk2oQlnfqq3Q1V6jJyKrFLrz@RhY7B3iKmYf440lInyvNYMHZyfKavPVQ5x8YZsEAA@AyCGwwJ8zMukFNooKe@Y/gLTC5Ciq6mD@jaPBdSvUBkpg9aBQGNciYJZwf8ehkeKnat79A3@vckcwZ3H/Wgg7OMOWc3ahvmMfsGYujF6ZO@Rva3DvUekuqLFyeSXsoUd2q/V6U75AiflwTAY/Z@GzMV9ba84b@AA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
←⁸↙Ｐ⁵↘←⁴↓Ｐ³↙Ｆ⁹⟦³⟧→Ｐ⁴↘Ｐ⁶
```

Output half of the circle.

```
↘‖ＯＭ←←¹⁷↘
```

Reflect it and draw in the bottom.

```
Ｆ⁹«Ｐ⁺³›ι³↑Ｐ⁴↗¿⁼ι²Ｂ⁸±²»
```

Draw the left arm and crossbar of the A.

```
↘→ＵＯ³¦¹⁴
```

Draw the right arm of the A.

```
ＵＭＫＡ#
```

Change all the characters to `#`s.

Answer (score 11):

## T-SQL, <s>341</s> 338 bytes

```
DECLARE @ CHAR(2000)=REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
'PRINT SPACE(14*6&$6*15&$4*5$4*10&$2*4$7*7$1*4&$1*3$8*4$1*3$3*3&*3$9*4$1*3$4
 *3&*3$8*4$2*3$4*3&*3$8*4$2*3$4*3&*3$7*4$3*3$4*3&*3$7*4$3*3$4*3&*3$6*11$4*3&
 *3$6*11$4*3&*3$5*4$5*3$4*3&*3$5*3$6*3$4*3&$1*4$2*4$11*4&$2*8$9*6&$6*17&$6*3)'
,'*',')+REPLICATE(''#'','),'$',')+SPACE('),'&',')+(''
''')EXEC(@)
```

The first 4 line breaks are for readability only, the final line break is part of a string literal.

Similar to my [Adam West tribute](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/126472/70172), I've manually encoded a long string, and made the following replacements:

- `*7` gets replaced by `+REPLICATE('#',7)`
- `$4` gets replaced by `+SPACE(4)`
- `&` gets replaced by a line break inside quotes

This results in a *massive* SQL command string:

```
PRINT SPACE(14)+REPLICATE('#',6)+('
')+SPACE(6)+REPLICATE('#',15)+('
')+SPACE(4)+REPLICATE('#',5)+SPACE(4)+REPLICATE('#',10)+('
')+SPACE(2)+REPLICATE('#',4)+SPACE(7)+REPLICATE('#',7)+SPACE(1)+REPLICATE('#',4)+('
')+SPACE(1)+REPLICATE('#',3)+SPACE(8)+REPLICATE('#',4)+SPACE(1)+REPLICATE('#',3)+SPACE(3)+REPLICATE('#',3)+('
')+REPLICATE('#',3)+SPACE(9)+REPLICATE('#',4)+SPACE(1)+REPLICATE('#',3)+SPACE(4)+REPLICATE('#',3)+('
')+REPLICATE('#',3)+SPACE(8)+REPLICATE('#',4)+SPACE(2)+REPLICATE('#',3)+SPACE(4)+REPLICATE('#',3)+('
')+REPLICATE('#',3)+SPACE(8)+REPLICATE('#',4)+SPACE(2)+REPLICATE('#',3)+SPACE(4)+REPLICATE('#',3)+('
')+REPLICATE('#',3)+SPACE(7)+REPLICATE('#',4)+SPACE(3)+REPLICATE('#',3)+SPACE(4)+REPLICATE('#',3)+('
')+REPLICATE('#',3)+SPACE(7)+REPLICATE('#',4)+SPACE(3)+REPLICATE('#',3)+SPACE(4)+REPLICATE('#',3)+('
')+REPLICATE('#',3)+SPACE(6)+REPLICATE('#',11)+SPACE(4)+REPLICATE('#',3)+('
')+REPLICATE('#',3)+SPACE(6)+REPLICATE('#',11)+SPACE(4)+REPLICATE('#',3)+('
')+REPLICATE('#',3)+SPACE(5)+REPLICATE('#',4)+SPACE(5)+REPLICATE('#',3)+SPACE(4)+REPLICATE('#',3)+('
')+REPLICATE('#',3)+SPACE(5)+REPLICATE('#',3)+SPACE(6)+REPLICATE('#',3)+SPACE(4)+REPLICATE('#',3)+('
')+SPACE(1)+REPLICATE('#',4)+SPACE(2)+REPLICATE('#',4)+SPACE(11)+REPLICATE('#',4)+('
')+SPACE(2)+REPLICATE('#',8)+SPACE(9)+REPLICATE('#',6)+('
')+SPACE(6)+REPLICATE('#',17)+('
')+SPACE(6)+REPLICATE('#',3)
```

Which, when run, produces the necessary output.

Long, but still better than my best set-based solution (**463 bytes**):

```
SELECT SPACE(a)+REPLICATE('#',b)+SPACE(c)+REPLICATE('#',d)
      +SPACE(e)+REPLICATE('#',f)+SPACE(g)+REPLICATE('#',h)
FROM(VALUES(7,0,7,6,0,0,0,0),(6,8,0,7,0,0,0,0),(4,5,4,5,0,5,0,0),(2,4,7,7,1,4,0,0),
           (1,3,8,4,1,3,3,3),(0,3,9,4,1,3,4,3),(0,3,8,4,2,3,4,3),(0,3,8,4,2,3,4,3),
           (0,3,7,4,3,3,4,3),(0,3,7,4,3,3,4,3),(0,3,6,6,0,5,4,3),(0,3,6,6,0,5,4,3),
           (0,3,5,4,5,3,4,3),(0,3,5,3,6,3,4,3),(1,4,2,4,5,0,6,4),(2,8,9,6,0,0,0,0),
           (6,9,0,8,0,0,0,0),(6,3,0,0,0,0,0,0))t(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)
```

Comment: can drop 2 chars using `CHAR(8000)` instead of `VARCHAR(max)` (the huge command is 1453 bytes)

Comment: Thanks, @Shameen. I tried to save one more and use `CHAR(2E3)` but it didn't seem to like that. I also saved a byte by using a line break literal instead of `CHAR(13)`.

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>173</s> 170 bytes

```javascript
_=>`tc
du
9a9k
58fe38
36h83676
6j83!h85!h85!f87!f87!dm96
6dm96
6b8b!b6d696
3858n8
5gjc
dy
d6`.split`!`.join`696
6`.replace(/./g,c=>'# '[(k=parseInt(c,36))&1].repeat(k/2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxLDoIwGIT3PYXEREqCEG0oPwvYewZjbOmDpy2BauLpseBiJpNvJtPzD1/E3E3ubKxUqy7XZ1kxJ5B8o4IXA8pAKwKI0BYIzSmiPZCghWyXhnyXfBW@@XsNdVBTSX0mkIEBlDW9//siSVmyTGPnWMCS3naGbSMPZzWNXCicJmkTi7IKj4fwjody4vOibsZhERMaRafLY5sq7vCQXqNoFdYsdlTJaBussQc/)

---

## [Node.js](https://nodejs.org), 163 bytes

Provided that an array of strings is a valid output:

```javascript
_=>Buffer(`.&-/*%$*&$''!$##($!###!#)$!#$&($"#$&($"#$&'$##$&'$##$&&+$&&+$&%$%#$&%#&#$#!$"$+$#()&(1*#2`).map(c=>s+='# '[x^=1].repeat(c-32),s=x='')&&s.match(/.{27}/g)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYpBDoIwFESvIvxP@wtSAi5clYXXMCqkFtQgEIqGxHj22sToYt7kZeZWP2urp@s4p/1wNq5R7qTK3aNpzESVZGkWRxgz5DxAAMIAAAIQvpERhn9yv/7Ikm8ijLxFwAAhwBATBBKM8hiKSsh7PZJWpU0UhxXfL0eVH@RkRlPPpNNNIdZWLYpzwZj151lfKJOvYvvOWuH00NuhM7IbWmpICPcB)

Answer (score 10):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), <s>74</s> <s>73</s> 71 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
ｑｃ２－Ａｚ↓n⁴╫ｍ┬ｆｆ╷＼_↘Tｔ)%⁵6＞Ｙy7pＱ∔Ｉ％SIŗ＋T＾≤?↔↖¶８^`O‾+Ｏ│≤n≡j↶82„２┬｛ #＠］∑‾＋ｎ
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjUxJXVGRjQzJXVGRjEyJXVGRjBEJXVGRjIxJXVGRjVBJXUyMTkzbiV1MjA3NCV1MjU2QiV1RkY0RCV1MjUyQyV1RkY0NiV1RkY0NiV1MjU3NyV1RkYzQ18ldTIxOThUJXVGRjU0JTI5JTI1JXUyMDc1NiV1RkYxRSV1RkYzOXk3cCV1RkYzMSV1MjIxNCV1RkYyOSV1RkYwNVNJJXUwMTU3JXVGRjBCVCV1RkYzRSV1MjI2NCUzRiV1MjE5NCV1MjE5NiVCNiV1RkYxOCU1RSU2ME8ldTIwM0UrJXVGRjJGJXUyNTAyJXUyMjY0biV1MjI2MWoldTIxQjY4MiV1MjAxRSV1RkYxMiV1MjUyQyV1RkY1QiUyMCUyMyV1RkYyMCV1RkYzRCV1MjIxMSV1MjAzRSV1RkYwQiV1RkY0RQ__,v=8)

Comment: im just curious, how u guys type those chars? u have special keyboard or something?

Comment: @NikkoKhresna 85% of my code is the data generated by a generator, but the last 11 bytes doing all the logic were typed in the [Canvas dev mode](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?v=8,dev) and spamming of tab after every char. That's only the case for me & Canvas though, e.g. AFAIK all of Jellys chars are typable with linux compose sequences.

Comment: @NikkoKhresna yeah, a lot of languages have different ways of typing the chars. some are typable with US keyboard (Jelly), some require pasting, and some (Charcoal, Actually and Sesos afaik) have a sort of verbose mode which only requires you to know the command names

Comment: @NikkoKhresna Charcoal also has (a very, very outdated) Linux keyboard, and probably some other languages too

Answer (score 10):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>174</s> <s>168</s> <s>164</s> 160 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to Dennis.

```c
i,j;main(l){while(i="NFMOJEDJFDGGADCCHDACCCACIDACDFHDBCDFHDBCDFGDCCDFGDCCDFFKDFFKDFEDECDFECFCDCADBDKDCHIFHQJC"[j++]&63)for(;i;)putchar(l++%28?--i,35-j%2*3:10);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYldC4IwGEb/i2BszUEpRTQi5vtuTqWi6@hCRuXEPpCii@i3LyHq4pzDw2P5yVrvXdSIc@UupKWvZ@3aA3GLYK1Xm0JhoTHLJAIYlAAgIe@L2mD6d9a/P@vyi0LVLwUaECSmWCKYXJttAcGuYWw/mCb0eO2IcILeHndbVx1pGQvj2ZJzFyUT3oTxMJmPR1S8vf8A)

Answer (score 10):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>101</s> <s>88</s> 64 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
„# •∍ΔÎë,½=bOÅ.âαUΔ'òõƶαÔγλ#xÆ]~”FbćÁ˜Ð”wнQ_wā©•12вεN>yи}˜èJ27ô»
```

-24 bytes by creating a port of [*@Dennis♦*' Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175891/52210).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##AXQAi/9vc2FiaWX//@KAniMg4oCi4oiNzpTDjsOrLMK9PWJPw4Uuw6LOsVXOlCfDssO1xrbOscOUzrPOuyN4w4ZdfuKAnUZixIfDgcucw5DigJ130L1RX3fEgcKp4oCiMTLQss61Tj550Lh9y5zDqEoyN8O0wrv//w)

**Explanation:**

```python
„#                     # Push string "# "
   •∍ΔÎë,½=bOÅ.âαUΔ'òõƶαÔγλ#xÆ]~”FbćÁ˜Ð”wнQ_wā©•
                      '# Push compressed integer 10250938842396786963034911279002199266186481794751691439873548591280332406943905758890346943197901909163
     12в               # Convert to Base-12 as list: [3,0,11,6,2,0,11,4,0,11,10,5,4,10,6,4,7,7,1,4,3,3,8,4,1,3,3,3,1,3,9,4,1,3,4,6,8,4,2,3,4,6,8,4,2,3,4,6,7,4,3,3,4,6,7,4,3,3,4,6,6,11,4,6,6,11,4,6,5,4,5,3,4,6,5,3,6,3,4,3,1,4,2,4,11,4,3,8,9,6,8,6,0,11,10,3]
        ε    }         # Map each `y` to:
         N>            #  The index+1
           yи          #  Repeated `y` amount of times
              ˜        # Flatten the list
               è       # Index each in the string "# " (with automatic wraparound)
                J      # Join everything together
                 27ô   # Split into parts of length 27
                    »  # And join by newlines
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to compress large integers?* and *How to compress integer lists?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand how the compression of the integer and list works.

Comment: You can save two bytes like this: `•∍ΔÎë,½=bOÅ.âαUΔ'òõƶαÔγλ#xÆ]~”FbćÁ˜Ð”wнQ_wā©•12вDg„ #s∍S×J27ô»` by replacing `„# ` and `εN>yи}˜è` with `Dg„ #s∍S×`

Answer (score 8):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 170 bytes

```
/+/\/\///*/  +)/'$# +(/"$!+'/" +&/!#+%/"!
!+$/*!+"/**+!/###/""('*
(!!!' 
"&#"!!&"
$#'$& &*
 !""& ! $ 
!"'& !%""&$%""&$%)$%)$%(&#%(&#%'&'!%'!"$"!
 &$#")
$&#"'!!*
(!!&#"
"$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU05DsMwDNv1CpFSJMca9KEuGQp06Jb/wzVS8AC5kPf3uj/ve62ufm10z1ats9NNazQdlU2taFgdTQjKe6LYcxbazJocOWUASBWGEQiKW3poTFGQoVBXAXOnY3f/2/lwhD3KSBwJ@r7RcOMpvucSeOZ3FPpaPw)

Answer (score 8):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>192</s> 176 bytes

```bash
dc<<<"16i2o81C0000 81FFFF0 9FE00FC BCF001E F070387 F078387 F03FF87 F03FF87 F01E387 F01E387 F00F387 F00F387 F007B87 B807B8E 9E03FBC 87C3FF0 81FFFC0 8001F80f"|tr 01 ' #'|cut -c2-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc2xDsIwDIThV7HK0KnSuZGIK2WKFb8HBCGYkKBsfffgwFRu@abTfz69bq1dakpp4ON9fggrfCRsPtBiBTClrAZwIUNEkNiVn8FsJ5ewE/ZnzG6WbqGl@DErSdTQe9@uul4zwXXY1ieBaaTDuNX3SlOdp9Y@)

-16 thanks to manatwork

This is similar to my C answer, except it just uses a raw base-16 compression and passes it through bc, then uses tr to convert 1 to # and 0 to space. Each row has 1 appended to it and stripped off of it to maintain alignment.

Unfortunately `dc` is shorter than `bc`.

Comment: No need for `^`. But even better, use `cut -c2-` instead of the `sed` part.

Comment: And also shorter with here-string instead of `echo` and even shorter with `dc` instead of `bc`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc2xDsIwDIThV7HK0KnSuZGIK2WKFb8HBCGYkKBsfffgwFRu@abTfz69bq1dakpp4ON9fggrfCRsPtBiBTClrAZwIUNEkNiVn8FsJ5ewE/ZnzG6WbqGl@DErSdTQe9@uul4zwXXY1ieBaaTDuNX3SlOdp9Y@ "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: I'll give you the `echo`, but come on - `dc` for Stan Lee... you must be joking ;)

Comment: [134 bytes](https://tio.run/##HcyxDgIhEATQX6E3JAuYYy@hYsN@hc2JhVZO9Ozu3znW6mUyk7lv3@cYj15KCcsrvpkoKIODqgo4S1LF2ihpFVSmXLlByczIc32BRSMG@Zv4as6OPKrMNjSs2ojs0Y51Ijj2jyN3c0f/7c736Mc4AQ "Bash – Try It Online")

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>136</s> 112 bytes

```perl6
:128['?@~p<?x?aB~<|xpqpac`?@~x>q|<!Ca`||?x'.ords].base(2)~~TR/1/ /.comb(27)>>.say
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/9/K0MgiWt2@3qG@joGhvsCGwZ69gkXGPpFPsN5JjrmOx4a9RqKCv6CwQD4xOcGegd2hjoGfscJOjrmwxkbRuT4xgb@GvYaBwb5CXS@/KKU4Vi8psThVw0izri4kSN9QX0FfLzk/N0nDyFzTzk6vOLHy/38A)

Parses a base 128 number from the ordinal values of the compressed string, converts to base 2 and replaces the `1`s with spaces. This uses zeroes as the main character. The string has like 9 null bytes, which was a bitch to type up in TIO. I would have used base 127 for the same amount of bytes, but no nulls, but that has a carriage return, which seems to be impossible to distinguish from a newline `:(`

#### Explanation:

```perl6
:128['...'.ords]   # Convert the bytes of the string to base 128
.base(2)           # Convert to base 2
~~TR/1/ /          # Translate 1s to spaces
                   # Alternatively, this could be .split(1)
.comb(27)          # Split to strings of length 27
>>.say             # Print each on a newline
```

Answer (score 6):

### Haskell, <s>170</s> 163 bytes

Edit: -7 bytes thanks to @Ørjan Johansen

```
m=<<"Mc Ul WeWg YdTgZa ZcSdZcX cRdZcW cSdYcW cSdYcW cTdXcW cTdXcW cUkW cUkW cVdVcW cVcUcW ZdYdPa YhRc Un U "
m ' '="###\n"
m c=(' '<$['Z','Y'..c])++('#'<$['a'..c])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxLDoIwFEXnruKFmhSDsgK6A00MUKAVB80rH0NpiOD2rUVjwuSenDO4vZqHxhjXstqNLEmCCwI3UDZlB0LnnVQgMdMSK8DUowRvYoNcVxvw4T@FLtZQIPeQWuirAtGn/t0Ch2A3AgXKAkJIbVdDFvqQ7G9U0iMVNI7xfoiikJJvVL/gRvWwwGB6LdnyPFto3Rtbo7rZnXCaPg)

Spaces are encoded as uppercase characters (length: `Z` down to char), hash signs as lowercase characters (length: `a` to char) and the last three `#` of each line plus newline as a space. Function `m` decodes it.

Comment: I think you can save some by letting space encode `"###\n"`.

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <strike>130</strike> 128 bytes

```
echo' #'{~18 27$;(_243{.2#.inv 92x#._32+a.i.])&>'!TYPW.ajz i8hIhXl''3lOH8GvV.C2Z{r/=,G';'"a*2ZDxRplkh2tzRakz.?ZwVmeOT6L^lFB^eyT'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I19dQVm9us7QQsHIXMVaI97IxLhaz0hZLzOvTMHSqEJZL97YSDtRL1MvVlPNTl0xJDIgXC8xq0oh0yLDMyMiR13dOMffw8K9LEzP2SiqukjfVsdd3VpdKVHLKMqlIqggJzvDqKQqKDG7Ss8@qjwsN9U/xMwnLsfNKS61MkT9/38A)

### Initial solution

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 164 bytes

```
echo' #'{~18 27$,#:849239965469633263905532594449192007713271791872263657753301928240007 12380965417202148347902847903517734495157419855048834759608223758433386496x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcw7CkJBEETRrQw84SUG3VX9dTsiiImpILj1cSappA73Nefj/nyf4zi/P62BvFyPW1mD3eEWHSSCLe6Et5m1NkQylUjN1kosEJ7ppKyzYLLAULBkRzQhUCtatqD20jWTK@bqadrlLlZbeIcUwPQykhXW8ZnzDw)

Answer (score 5):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>286</s> <s>212</s> <s>209</s> 208 bytes

```php
<?php foreach(str_split('000680018y4g04uj1s0iql6k0yz98u1xxu2v1xyhs71xyhs71xzt6v1xzt6v1y2ruv1y2ruv1y7pmv1y70cn121jq60jwdto018y5s13bwg',6)as $i)echo str_replace(0,' ',str_pad(base_convert($i,36,2),27,0,0))."
";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc7dCoIwGMbx865iSOAGI96tmkZBlxJzLqdZzn340c0bQnXyO/gfPDzW2GW5XK2x6N45LZXBPribt20dcAoAIgdg@Xyo4BAb5qHuW/GA@X3KI5umyAc2zcZnP99BDF9n7uLfzD5XQb0YZ00voBnL0K3LR8/2xVilVBDp0bYmWpkOrSectq1UGgNNUUrXYmWJC@n1TXWvQbuAtzXdC8oJ5RkFCoTskk1yXpYP)

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 181 bytes

```perl
say+(sprintf"%28b",oct"0x$_")=~y/10/# /r for"0003f0003fff800f87fe03c07f78700f71ce00f70ee01e70ee01e70ee03c70ee03c70ee07ff0ee07ff0ee0f070ee0e070e79e003c3fc01f803fffe00380000"=~/.{7}/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc1BCsIwFATQq5SooKjNxJgmLnoEzyAa8qUgTUm7sIg9ujHpqpt5/Fn86Vx4qRj7@7jf9l1o2oHY5mQe7ODtwPBe39iunkYuwFcFDwX5wABImoPIAGQ0OUgLTdrodGthXQbOQbgl0i7RRAsIc@ky@pIeSCvJQqSJPJSLNAaweuLlR3/5M8ZKyXMlVaKSKX6@Gxrf9vF4VSUE/g)

Answer (score 4):

[**MATLAB**](https://se.mathworks.com/products/matlab.html) **: 144 Bytes**

```
reshape(repelem([repmat(' #',1,44),' '],'NFMOJEDJFDGGADCCHDACCCACIDACDFHDBCDFHDBCDFGDCCDFGDCCDFFKDFFKDFEDECDFECFCDCADBDKDCHIFHQJCR'-64),27,[])'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYnLCsIwFER/peDiJhAXleBzld6bR1NU7LZkUSTgwmJpi78fA6KLOXOGed2X/h1TmuL86MfIpjjGZxxm1mUb@oVBsQJRCim5gAKC6Mrj/nCCizlfvSZvyFpFiI4UIiqsc5NxVP1p8/ujab7RpPPSaJBQUUUNoauNu3lsYb2VgYvNTnSBQ0of) (Technically in Octave)

**Explanation:**

This uses the same strategy as digEmAll in R, just with MATLAB syntax. The main difference is that MATLAB has automatic conversion from characters to integers.

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 199 bytes

```cs
_=>{var r="";for(int i=0,j,k=0;i<88;i++)for(j=0;j++<"0(/1,'&,(&))#&%%*&#%%%#%+&#%&(*&$%&(*&$%&()&%%&()&%%&((-&((-&('&'%&('%(%&%#&$&-&%*+(*3,%"[i]-34;){r+=i%2<1?' ':'#';if(++k%27<1)r+='\n';}return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU/JasMwFLznK4Sdp8Wy0yyFhspOD4WeWijk0EMaiuoqRllkkJRACf52V4mpe@nAm7fMm8OULitrq9pyL51Dr7aurDwMUMD5yhc4L70u0anWX@hFakOdt9pUqzWStnKs//tzXLD8dl4dRk9HU@adIe3aAn1Kf5AGFe1HsTifpEW2iCKxqS3VxiNdjNNtuivGQufzudCcs4u0DYct53k0pjeTlOCUYsZiDJDgGABi4KFjmuBhzyyov0yzrggmYSNAAUOMhzjDkHCazFKIVnqdzW4FO1teaJjmkweCyD2JidAbyvkOpnf5hAWRvBsiGqv80RpkRdOKwX/RH2vj6r0avVntFe1C02jpQ/RnpSLGRO9qrlPT/gA)

Uses the same approach as my solution to the [tribute to Adam West](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/126301/70347).

Comment: [190 bytes](https://tio.run/##bU9NawIxFLz7K0LWl002q/WjUGk29lDoqYWChx6slHSbSlbNQhKFIv72Nbp0e@nAm/cxbw5T@kFZO92UW@U9enX12qldD0Ucr3yBDyqYEh1q84VelLHUB2fserlCyq096/7@HBcsfnzQu@HT3pZFa8jbNkefKuyURbL5kPPjQTnkJMbiu3bU2ICMHOVVvpEjYYrZTBjO2UWq5PRWVJwXeERvxnlKckoYSwhARhIASIDHTmhG@h2zqP4yHbSVkjRuKVAgkJA@GRDIOM2mOeClWQnHJecbmNwV4wf8bvE9xizeMEqiDJP4oMPeWeTEqRG9/xI/1tbXWz18cyZo2maleBFi4metMWOic52u06k5Aw "C# (.NET Core) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), <strike>726</strike> 723 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to [@squid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85755/squid)*

```
{iii}ii{c}cccciccccccddd{dd}c{ii}iicccccci{c}cccccddd{dd}c{ii}iiccccicccccdcccci{c}ddd{dd}c{ii}iicciccccdcccccccicccccccdciccccddd{dd}c{ii}iicicccdcccccccciccccdcicccdcccicccddd{dd}c{ii}iiicccdccccccccciccccdcicccdccccicccddd{dd}c{ii}iiicccdcccccccciccccdccicccdccccicccddd{dd}c{ii}iiicccdcccccccciccccdccicccdccccicccddd{dd}c{ii}iiicccdccccccciccccdcccicccdccccicccddd{dd}c{ii}iiicccdccccccciccccdcccicccdccccicccddd{dd}c{ii}iiicccdcccccci{c}cdccccicccddd{dd}c{ii}iiicccdcccccci{c}cdccccicccddd{dd}c{ii}iiicccdccccciccccdcccccicccdccccicccddd{dd}c{ii}iiicccdcccccicccdccccccicccdccccicccddd{dd}c{ii}iiciccccdcciccccd{c}ciccccddd{dd}c{ii}iicciccccccccdccccccccciccccccddd{dd}c{ii}iicccccci{c}cccccccddd{dd}c{ii}iicccccciccc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZJBDoAgDARf5KNMV@OePRLejggpAkLwIE040B1oYYttxc7zWJwzJC1pxIoPSggABrBighZzijTESECpGmBSnwp@z8ZlzEg9pzm@8IKu8RGvXU3i06Pn8MGNv7DMoE/V8wJ9vvgxwd1Jy/I0EbWVgzHsyH45dwE)

---

Having never seen/read anything Marvel and only relying on spoilers, it seems that Thanos is the best.

Comment: [-3 bytes](https://tio.run/##tZJBDoAgDARf5KNMV@OePRLejggpAkLwIE040B1oYYttxc7zWJwzJC1pxIoPSggABrBighZzijTESECpGmBSnwp@z8ZlzEg9pzm@8IKu8RGvXU3i06Pn8MGNv7DMoE/V8wJ9vvgxwd1Jy/I0EbWVgzHsyH45dwE)

Answer (score 2):

### [Turing Machine But Way Worse](https://github.com/MilkyWay90/Turing-Machine-But-Way-Worse) - 16913 bytes

```
0 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 1 0 1 2 0 0
0 2 1 0 3 1 0
0 3 0 1 0 1 0
1 0 1 1 4 1 0
0 4 0 1 5 1 0
0 5 0 0 6 1 0
0 6 0 1 7 1 0
0 7 0 0 8 1 0
0 8 0 1 9 1 0
0 9 0 0 10 1 0
0 10 0 1 11 1 0
0 11 0 0 12 1 0
0 12 0 1 13 1 0
0 13 0 0 14 1 0
0 14 0 1 15 1 0
0 15 0 1 16 0 0
0 16 0 1 17 0 0
0 17 1 1 18 0 0
0 18 1 0 1 1 0
1 1 1 0 19 1 0
0 19 0 0 20 1 0
0 20 0 0 21 1 0
0 21 0 1 22 1 0
0 22 0 0 23 1 0
0 23 0 0 2 0 0
1 2 0 0 24 0 0
0 24 0 1 25 0 0
0 25 0 1 26 0 0
0 26 0 1 27 0 0
0 27 1 1 28 0 0
0 28 0 1 3 0 0
1 3 1 1 4 0 0
1 4 0 0 5 1 0
1 5 0 0 29 0 0
0 29 0 0 6 0 0
1 6 0 0 30 0 0
0 30 0 0 31 0 0
0 31 1 0 32 1 0
0 32 0 1 7 1 0
1 7 1 1 33 1 0
0 33 0 1 34 1 0
0 34 0 0 35 1 0
0 35 0 1 36 1 0
0 36 0 1 37 0 0
0 37 0 1 38 0 0
0 38 1 1 39 0 0
0 39 1 0 8 1 0
1 8 1 0 40 1 0
0 40 0 0 41 1 0
0 41 0 0 42 1 0
0 42 0 1 43 1 0
0 43 0 0 44 1 0
0 44 0 1 45 1 0
0 45 0 0 46 1 0
0 46 0 1 47 1 0
0 47 0 0 48 1 0
0 48 0 1 49 1 0
0 49 0 0 50 1 0
0 50 0 1 51 1 0
0 51 0 0 52 1 0
0 52 0 1 53 1 0
0 53 1 1 54 0 0
0 54 0 1 9 0 0
1 9 1 1 10 0 0
1 10 0 0 11 0 0
1 11 1 0 55 0 0
0 55 0 0 12 0 0
1 12 1 0 56 0 0
0 56 0 0 13 0 0
1 13 0 0 57 1 0
0 57 0 1 58 0 0
0 58 1 0 59 0 0
0 59 0 1 14 0 0
1 14 1 1 60 0 0
0 60 0 1 15 0 0
1 15 0 1 61 0 0
0 61 0 1 16 0 0
1 16 0 0 62 1 0
0 62 0 0 63 1 0
0 63 0 0 64 1 0
0 64 0 1 65 1 0
0 65 0 1 66 0 0
0 66 0 1 67 0 0
0 67 1 1 68 0 0
0 68 1 0 17 1 0
1 17 1 0 69 1 0
0 69 0 0 70 1 0
0 70 0 0 71 1 0
0 71 0 1 72 1 0
0 72 0 1 73 0 0
0 73 0 1 18 0 0
1 18 0 1 19 0 0
1 19 0 0 74 1 0
0 74 0 0 75 1 0
0 75 0 0 76 1 0
0 76 0 0 77 1 0
0 77 0 1 78 0 0
0 78 0 1 79 0 0
0 79 0 1 80 0 0
0 80 1 1 81 0 0
0 81 1 0 20 1 0
1 20 1 0 82 1 0
0 82 0 0 83 1 0
0 83 0 0 84 1 0
0 84 0 1 85 1 0
0 85 0 0 86 1 0
0 86 0 1 87 1 0
0 87 0 0 88 1 0
0 88 0 1 89 1 0
0 89 0 0 90 1 0
0 90 0 0 21 0 0
1 21 0 0 91 0 0
0 91 0 1 92 0 0
0 92 0 1 93 0 0
0 93 0 1 94 0 0
0 94 1 1 95 0 0
0 95 0 1 22 0 0
1 22 1 1 23 0 0
1 23 0 0 24 1 0
1 24 0 0 96 0 0
0 96 0 0 25 0 0
1 25 0 0 97 0 0
0 97 0 0 98 0 0
0 98 1 0 99 1 0
0 99 0 1 26 1 0
1 26 1 1 100 0 0
0 100 0 1 101 0 0
0 101 0 1 102 0 0
0 102 0 1 103 0 0
0 103 1 1 104 0 0
0 104 1 0 27 1 0
1 27 1 0 105 1 0
0 105 0 0 106 1 0
0 106 0 0 107 1 0
0 107 0 1 108 0 0
0 108 0 1 109 0 0
0 109 0 1 28 0 0
1 28 0 1 29 0 0
1 29 0 0 110 1 0
0 110 0 0 111 1 0
0 111 0 0 112 1 0
0 112 0 0 113 1 0
0 113 0 1 114 1 0
0 114 0 0 115 1 0
0 115 0 1 116 1 0
0 116 0 1 117 0 0
0 117 0 1 118 0 0
0 118 1 1 119 0 0
0 119 1 0 30 1 0
1 30 1 0 120 1 0
0 120 0 0 121 1 0
0 121 0 0 122 1 0
0 122 0 1 123 1 0
0 123 0 0 124 1 0
0 124 0 1 125 1 0
0 125 0 1 126 0 0
0 126 0 1 31 0 0
1 31 0 1 32 0 0
1 32 0 0 127 1 0
0 127 1 1 128 0 0
0 128 1 0 33 1 0
1 33 1 0 129 1 0
0 129 0 0 130 1 0
0 130 0 0 131 1 0
0 131 0 0 34 0 0
1 34 0 0 132 0 0
0 132 0 1 133 0 0
0 133 0 1 134 0 0
0 134 0 1 135 0 0
0 135 1 1 136 0 0
0 136 0 1 35 0 0
1 35 1 1 36 0 0
1 36 0 0 37 1 0
1 37 0 0 137 0 0
0 137 0 0 38 0 0
1 38 0 0 138 0 0
0 138 0 0 139 0 0
0 139 1 0 140 1 0
0 140 0 1 39 0 0
1 39 1 1 141 0 0
0 141 0 1 142 0 0
0 142 0 1 143 0 0
0 143 0 1 144 0 0
0 144 1 1 145 0 0
0 145 1 0 40 1 0
1 40 1 0 146 1 0
0 146 0 0 147 1 0
0 147 0 1 148 0 0
0 148 0 1 41 0 0
1 41 0 1 42 0 0
1 42 0 0 149 1 0
0 149 0 0 150 1 0
0 150 0 0 151 1 0
0 151 0 0 152 1 0
0 152 0 1 153 1 0
0 153 0 0 154 1 0
0 154 0 1 155 1 0
0 155 0 0 156 1 0
0 156 0 1 157 0 0
0 157 0 1 158 0 0
0 158 0 1 159 0 0
0 159 1 1 160 0 0
0 160 1 0 43 1 0
1 43 1 0 161 1 0
0 161 0 0 162 1 0
0 162 0 0 163 1 0
0 163 0 1 164 0 0
0 164 0 1 165 0 0
0 165 0 1 44 0 0
1 44 0 1 45 0 0
1 45 0 0 166 1 0
0 166 1 1 167 0 0
0 167 1 0 46 1 0
1 46 1 0 168 1 0
0 168 0 0 169 1 0
0 169 0 1 170 0 0
0 170 0 1 47 0 0
1 47 0 1 48 0 0
1 48 0 0 171 1 0
0 171 0 0 172 1 0
0 172 0 0 173 1 0
0 173 0 1 174 0 0
0 174 0 1 175 0 0
0 175 1 1 176 0 0
0 176 1 0 49 1 0
1 49 1 0 177 1 0
0 177 0 0 178 1 0
0 178 1 1 179 0 0
0 179 0 1 50 0 0
1 50 1 1 51 0 0
1 51 0 0 52 0 0
1 52 1 0 180 0 0
0 180 0 0 53 0 0
1 53 1 0 181 0 0
0 181 0 0 54 0 0
1 54 0 0 182 1 0
0 182 0 1 183 0 0
0 183 1 0 184 0 0
0 184 0 1 55 0 0
1 55 1 1 185 0 0
0 185 0 1 56 0 0
1 56 0 1 186 0 0
0 186 0 1 57 0 0
1 57 1 1 187 0 0
0 187 1 0 58 1 0
1 58 1 0 188 1 0
0 188 0 0 189 1 0
0 189 0 1 190 0 0
0 190 0 1 59 0 0
1 59 0 1 60 0 0
1 60 0 0 191 1 0
0 191 0 0 192 1 0
0 192 0 0 193 1 0
0 193 0 0 194 1 0
0 194 0 1 195 1 0
0 195 0 0 196 1 0
0 196 0 1 197 1 0
0 197 0 0 198 1 0
0 198 0 1 199 1 0
0 199 0 1 200 0 0
0 200 0 1 201 0 0
0 201 1 1 202 0 0
0 202 1 0 61 1 0
1 61 1 0 203 1 0
0 203 0 0 204 1 0
0 204 0 0 205 1 0
0 205 0 1 206 0 0
0 206 0 1 207 0 0
0 207 0 1 62 0 0
1 62 0 1 63 0 0
1 63 0 0 208 1 0
0 208 1 1 209 0 0
0 209 1 0 64 1 0
1 64 1 0 210 1 0
0 210 0 0 211 1 0
0 211 0 1 212 0 0
0 212 0 1 65 0 0
1 65 0 1 66 0 0
1 66 0 0 213 1 0
0 213 0 0 214 1 0
0 214 0 0 215 1 0
0 215 0 0 216 1 0
0 216 0 1 217 0 0
0 217 0 1 218 0 0
0 218 0 1 219 0 0
0 219 1 1 220 0 0
0 220 1 0 67 1 0
1 67 1 0 221 1 0
0 221 0 0 222 1 0
0 222 1 1 223 0 0
0 223 0 1 68 0 0
1 68 1 1 69 0 0
1 69 0 0 70 0 0
1 70 1 0 224 0 0
0 224 0 0 71 0 0
1 71 1 0 225 0 0
0 225 0 0 72 0 0
1 72 0 0 226 1 0
0 226 0 1 227 0 0
0 227 1 0 228 0 0
0 228 0 1 73 0 0
1 73 1 1 229 0 0
0 229 0 1 74 0 0
1 74 0 1 230 0 0
0 230 0 1 75 0 0
1 75 1 1 231 0 0
0 231 1 0 76 1 0
1 76 1 0 232 1 0
0 232 0 0 233 1 0
0 233 0 1 234 0 0
0 234 0 1 77 0 0
1 77 0 1 78 0 0
1 78 0 0 235 1 0
0 235 0 0 236 1 0
0 236 0 0 237 1 0
0 237 0 0 238 1 0
0 238 0 1 239 1 0
0 239 0 0 240 1 0
0 240 0 1 241 1 0
0 241 0 0 242 1 0
0 242 0 1 243 0 0
0 243 0 1 244 0 0
0 244 0 1 245 0 0
0 245 1 1 246 0 0
0 246 1 0 79 1 0
1 79 1 0 247 1 0
0 247 0 0 248 1 0
0 248 0 0 249 1 0
0 249 0 1 250 0 0
0 250 0 1 251 0 0
0 251 0 1 80 0 0
1 80 0 1 81 0 0
1 81 0 0 252 1 0
0 252 0 0 253 1 0
0 253 0 1 254 0 0
0 254 1 1 255 0 0
0 255 1 0 82 1 0
1 82 1 0 256 1 0
0 256 0 0 257 1 0
0 257 0 1 258 0 0
0 258 0 1 83 0 0
1 83 0 1 84 0 0
1 84 0 0 259 1 0
0 259 0 0 260 1 0
0 260 0 0 261 1 0
0 261 0 0 262 1 0
0 262 0 1 263 0 0
0 263 0 1 264 0 0
0 264 0 1 265 0 0
0 265 1 1 266 0 0
0 266 1 0 85 1 0
1 85 1 0 267 1 0
0 267 0 0 268 1 0
0 268 1 1 269 0 0
0 269 0 1 86 0 0
1 86 1 1 87 0 0
1 87 0 0 88 0 0
1 88 1 0 270 0 0
0 270 0 0 89 0 0
1 89 1 0 271 0 0
0 271 0 0 90 0 0
1 90 0 0 272 1 0
0 272 0 1 273 0 0
0 273 1 0 274 0 0
0 274 0 1 91 0 0
1 91 1 1 275 0 0
0 275 0 1 92 0 0
1 92 0 1 276 0 0
0 276 0 1 93 0 0
1 93 1 1 277 0 0
0 277 1 0 94 1 0
1 94 1 0 278 1 0
0 278 0 0 279 1 0
0 279 0 1 280 0 0
0 280 0 1 95 0 0
1 95 0 1 96 0 0
1 96 0 0 281 1 0
0 281 0 0 282 1 0
0 282 0 0 283 1 0
0 283 0 0 284 1 0
0 284 0 1 285 1 0
0 285 0 0 286 1 0
0 286 0 1 287 1 0
0 287 0 0 288 1 0
0 288 0 1 289 0 0
0 289 0 1 290 0 0
0 290 0 1 291 0 0
0 291 1 1 292 0 0
0 292 1 0 97 1 0
1 97 1 0 293 1 0
0 293 0 0 294 1 0
0 294 0 0 295 1 0
0 295 0 1 296 0 0
0 296 0 1 297 0 0
0 297 0 1 98 0 0
1 98 0 1 99 0 0
1 99 0 0 298 1 0
0 298 0 0 299 1 0
0 299 0 1 300 0 0
0 300 1 1 301 0 0
0 301 1 0 100 1 0
1 100 1 0 302 1 0
0 302 0 0 303 1 0
0 303 0 1 304 0 0
0 304 0 1 101 0 0
1 101 0 1 102 0 0
1 102 0 0 305 1 0
0 305 0 0 306 1 0
0 306 0 0 307 1 0
0 307 0 0 308 1 0
0 308 0 1 309 0 0
0 309 0 1 310 0 0
0 310 0 1 311 0 0
0 311 1 1 312 0 0
0 312 1 0 103 1 0
1 103 1 0 313 1 0
0 313 0 0 314 1 0
0 314 1 1 315 0 0
0 315 0 1 104 0 0
1 104 1 1 105 0 0
1 105 0 0 106 0 0
1 106 1 0 316 0 0
0 316 0 0 107 0 0
1 107 1 0 317 0 0
0 317 0 0 108 0 0
1 108 0 0 318 1 0
0 318 0 1 319 0 0
0 319 1 0 320 0 0
0 320 0 1 109 0 0
1 109 1 1 321 0 0
0 321 0 1 110 0 0
1 110 0 1 322 0 0
0 322 0 1 111 0 0
1 111 1 1 323 0 0
0 323 1 0 112 1 0
1 112 1 0 324 1 0
0 324 0 0 325 1 0
0 325 0 1 326 0 0
0 326 0 1 113 0 0
1 113 0 1 114 0 0
1 114 0 0 327 1 0
0 327 0 0 328 1 0
0 328 0 0 329 1 0
0 329 0 0 330 1 0
0 330 0 1 331 1 0
0 331 0 0 332 1 0
0 332 0 1 333 1 0
0 333 0 1 334 0 0
0 334 0 1 335 0 0
0 335 1 1 336 0 0
0 336 1 0 115 1 0
1 115 1 0 337 1 0
0 337 0 0 338 1 0
0 338 0 0 339 1 0
0 339 0 1 340 0 0
0 340 0 1 341 0 0
0 341 0 1 116 0 0
1 116 0 1 117 0 0
1 117 0 0 342 1 0
0 342 0 0 343 1 0
0 343 0 0 344 1 0
0 344 0 1 345 0 0
0 345 0 1 346 0 0
0 346 1 1 347 0 0
0 347 1 0 118 1 0
1 118 1 0 348 1 0
0 348 0 0 349 1 0
0 349 0 1 350 0 0
0 350 0 1 119 0 0
1 119 0 1 120 0 0
1 120 0 0 351 1 0
0 351 0 0 352 1 0
0 352 0 0 353 1 0
0 353 0 0 354 1 0
0 354 0 1 355 0 0
0 355 0 1 356 0 0
0 356 0 1 357 0 0
0 357 1 1 358 0 0
0 358 1 0 121 1 0
1 121 1 0 359 1 0
0 359 0 0 360 1 0
0 360 1 1 361 0 0
0 361 0 1 122 0 0
1 122 1 1 123 0 0
1 123 0 0 124 0 0
1 124 1 0 362 0 0
0 362 0 0 125 0 0
1 125 1 0 363 0 0
0 363 0 0 126 0 0
1 126 0 0 364 1 0
0 364 0 1 365 0 0
0 365 1 0 366 0 0
0 366 0 1 127 0 0
1 127 1 1 367 0 0
0 367 0 1 128 0 0
1 128 0 1 368 0 0
0 368 0 1 129 0 0
1 129 1 1 369 0 0
0 369 1 0 130 1 0
1 130 1 0 370 1 0
0 370 0 0 371 1 0
0 371 0 1 372 0 0
0 372 0 1 131 0 0
1 131 0 1 132 0 0
1 132 0 0 373 1 0
0 373 0 0 374 1 0
0 374 0 0 375 1 0
0 375 0 0 376 1 0
0 376 0 1 377 1 0
0 377 0 0 378 1 0
0 378 0 1 379 1 0
0 379 0 1 380 0 0
0 380 0 1 381 0 0
0 381 1 1 382 0 0
0 382 1 0 133 1 0
1 133 1 0 383 1 0
0 383 0 0 384 1 0
0 384 0 0 385 1 0
0 385 0 1 386 0 0
0 386 0 1 387 0 0
0 387 0 1 134 0 0
1 134 0 1 135 0 0
1 135 0 0 388 1 0
0 388 0 0 389 1 0
0 389 0 0 390 1 0
0 390 0 1 391 0 0
0 391 0 1 392 0 0
0 392 1 1 393 0 0
0 393 1 0 136 1 0
1 136 1 0 394 1 0
0 394 0 0 395 1 0
0 395 0 1 396 0 0
0 396 0 1 137 0 0
1 137 0 1 138 0 0
1 138 0 0 397 1 0
0 397 0 0 398 1 0
0 398 0 0 399 1 0
0 399 0 0 400 1 0
0 400 0 1 401 0 0
0 401 0 1 402 0 0
0 402 0 1 403 0 0
0 403 1 1 404 0 0
0 404 1 0 139 1 0
1 139 1 0 405 1 0
0 405 0 0 406 1 0
0 406 1 1 407 0 0
0 407 0 1 140 0 0
1 140 1 1 141 0 0
1 141 0 0 142 0 0
1 142 1 0 408 0 0
0 408 0 0 143 0 0
1 143 1 0 409 0 0
0 409 0 0 144 0 0
1 144 0 0 410 1 0
0 410 0 1 411 0 0
0 411 1 0 412 0 0
0 412 0 1 145 0 0
1 145 1 1 413 0 0
0 413 0 1 146 0 0
1 146 0 1 414 0 0
0 414 0 1 147 0 0
1 147 1 1 415 0 0
0 415 1 0 148 1 0
1 148 1 0 416 1 0
0 416 0 0 417 1 0
0 417 0 1 418 0 0
0 418 0 1 149 0 0
1 149 0 1 150 0 0
1 150 0 0 419 1 0
0 419 0 0 420 1 0
0 420 0 0 421 1 0
0 421 0 0 422 1 0
0 422 0 1 423 1 0
0 423 0 0 424 1 0
0 424 0 1 425 0 0
0 425 0 1 426 0 0
0 426 0 1 427 0 0
0 427 1 1 428 0 0
0 428 1 0 151 1 0
1 151 1 0 429 1 0
0 429 0 0 430 1 0
0 430 0 0 431 1 0
0 431 0 1 432 1 0
0 432 0 0 433 1 0
0 433 0 1 434 1 0
0 434 0 0 435 1 0
0 435 0 1 436 1 0
0 436 0 0 437 1 0
0 437 0 1 438 1 0
0 438 0 1 439 0 0
0 439 0 1 152 0 0
1 152 0 1 153 0 0
1 153 0 0 440 1 0
0 440 0 0 441 1 0
0 441 0 0 442 1 0
0 442 0 0 443 1 0
0 443 0 1 444 0 0
0 444 0 1 445 0 0
0 445 0 1 446 0 0
0 446 1 1 447 0 0
0 447 1 0 154 1 0
1 154 1 0 448 1 0
0 448 0 0 449 1 0
0 449 1 1 450 0 0
0 450 0 1 155 0 0
1 155 1 1 156 0 0
1 156 0 0 157 0 0
1 157 1 0 451 0 0
0 451 0 0 158 0 0
1 158 1 0 452 0 0
0 452 0 0 159 0 0
1 159 0 0 453 1 0
0 453 0 1 454 0 0
0 454 1 0 455 0 0
0 455 0 1 160 0 0
1 160 1 1 456 0 0
0 456 0 1 161 0 0
1 161 0 1 457 0 0
0 457 0 1 162 0 0
1 162 1 1 458 0 0
0 458 1 0 163 1 0
1 163 1 0 459 1 0
0 459 0 0 460 1 0
0 460 0 1 461 0 0
0 461 0 1 164 0 0
1 164 0 1 165 0 0
1 165 0 0 462 1 0
0 462 0 0 463 1 0
0 463 0 0 464 1 0
0 464 0 0 465 1 0
0 465 0 1 466 1 0
0 466 0 0 467 1 0
0 467 0 1 468 0 0
0 468 0 1 469 0 0
0 469 0 1 470 0 0
0 470 1 1 471 0 0
0 471 1 0 166 1 0
1 166 1 0 472 1 0
0 472 0 0 473 1 0
0 473 0 0 474 1 0
0 474 0 1 475 1 0
0 475 0 0 476 1 0
0 476 0 1 477 1 0
0 477 0 0 478 1 0
0 478 0 1 479 1 0
0 479 0 0 480 1 0
0 480 0 1 481 1 0
0 481 0 1 482 0 0
0 482 0 1 167 0 0
1 167 0 1 168 0 0
1 168 0 0 483 1 0
0 483 0 0 484 1 0
0 484 0 0 485 1 0
0 485 0 0 486 1 0
0 486 0 1 487 0 0
0 487 0 1 488 0 0
0 488 0 1 489 0 0
0 489 1 1 490 0 0
0 490 1 0 169 1 0
1 169 1 0 491 1 0
0 491 0 0 492 1 0
0 492 1 1 493 0 0
0 493 0 1 170 0 0
1 170 1 1 171 0 0
1 171 0 0 172 0 0
1 172 1 0 494 0 0
0 494 0 0 173 0 0
1 173 1 0 495 0 0
0 495 0 0 174 0 0
1 174 0 0 496 1 0
0 496 0 1 497 0 0
0 497 1 0 498 0 0
0 498 0 1 175 0 0
1 175 1 1 499 0 0
0 499 0 1 176 0 0
1 176 0 1 500 0 0
0 500 0 1 177 0 0
1 177 1 1 501 0 0
0 501 1 0 178 1 0
1 178 1 0 502 1 0
0 502 0 0 503 1 0
0 503 0 1 504 0 0
0 504 0 1 179 0 0
1 179 0 1 180 0 0
1 180 0 0 505 1 0
0 505 0 0 506 1 0
0 506 0 0 507 1 0
0 507 0 0 508 1 0
0 508 0 1 509 1 0
0 509 0 1 510 0 0
0 510 0 1 511 0 0
0 511 1 1 512 0 0
0 512 1 0 181 1 0
1 181 1 0 513 1 0
0 513 0 0 514 1 0
0 514 0 0 515 1 0
0 515 0 1 516 0 0
0 516 0 1 517 0 0
0 517 0 1 182 0 0
1 182 0 1 183 0 0
1 183 0 0 518 1 0
0 518 0 0 519 1 0
0 519 0 0 520 1 0
0 520 0 0 521 1 0
0 521 0 1 522 1 0
0 522 0 1 523 0 0
0 523 0 1 524 0 0
0 524 1 1 525 0 0
0 525 1 0 184 1 0
1 184 1 0 526 1 0
0 526 0 0 527 1 0
0 527 0 1 528 0 0
0 528 0 1 185 0 0
1 185 0 1 186 0 0
1 186 0 0 529 1 0
0 529 0 0 530 1 0
0 530 0 0 531 1 0
0 531 0 0 532 1 0
0 532 0 1 533 0 0
0 533 0 1 534 0 0
0 534 0 1 535 0 0
0 535 1 1 536 0 0
0 536 1 0 187 1 0
1 187 1 0 537 1 0
0 537 0 0 538 1 0
0 538 1 1 539 0 0
0 539 0 1 188 0 0
1 188 1 1 189 0 0
1 189 0 0 190 0 0
1 190 1 0 540 0 0
0 540 0 0 191 0 0
1 191 1 0 541 0 0
0 541 0 0 192 0 0
1 192 0 0 542 1 0
0 542 0 1 543 0 0
0 543 1 0 544 0 0
0 544 0 1 193 0 0
1 193 1 1 545 0 0
0 545 0 1 194 0 0
1 194 0 1 546 0 0
0 546 0 1 195 0 0
1 195 1 1 547 0 0
0 547 1 0 196 1 0
1 196 1 0 548 1 0
0 548 0 0 549 1 0
0 549 0 1 550 0 0
0 550 0 1 197 0 0
1 197 0 1 198 0 0
1 198 0 0 551 1 0
0 551 0 0 552 1 0
0 552 0 0 553 1 0
0 553 0 0 554 1 0
0 554 0 1 555 1 0
0 555 0 1 556 0 0
0 556 0 1 557 0 0
0 557 1 1 558 0 0
0 558 1 0 199 1 0
1 199 1 0 559 1 0
0 559 0 0 560 1 0
0 560 0 1 561 0 0
0 561 0 1 200 0 0
1 200 0 1 201 0 0
1 201 0 0 562 1 0
0 562 0 0 563 1 0
0 563 0 0 564 1 0
0 564 0 0 565 1 0
0 565 0 1 566 1 0
0 566 0 0 567 1 0
0 567 0 1 568 0 0
0 568 0 1 569 0 0
0 569 0 1 570 0 0
0 570 1 1 571 0 0
0 571 1 0 202 1 0
1 202 1 0 572 1 0
0 572 0 0 573 1 0
0 573 0 1 574 0 0
0 574 0 1 203 0 0
1 203 0 1 204 0 0
1 204 0 0 575 1 0
0 575 0 0 576 1 0
0 576 0 0 577 1 0
0 577 0 0 578 1 0
0 578 0 1 579 0 0
0 579 0 1 580 0 0
0 580 0 1 581 0 0
0 581 1 1 582 0 0
0 582 1 0 205 1 0
1 205 1 0 583 1 0
0 583 0 0 584 1 0
0 584 1 1 585 0 0
0 585 0 1 206 0 0
1 206 1 1 207 0 0
1 207 0 0 208 0 0
1 208 1 0 586 0 0
0 586 0 0 209 0 0
1 209 1 0 587 0 0
0 587 0 0 210 0 0
1 210 0 0 588 1 0
0 588 0 1 589 0 0
0 589 1 0 590 0 0
0 590 0 1 211 0 0
1 211 1 1 591 0 0
0 591 0 1 212 0 0
1 212 0 1 592 0 0
0 592 0 1 213 0 0
1 213 0 0 593 1 0
0 593 0 1 594 0 0
0 594 1 1 595 0 0
0 595 1 0 214 1 0
1 214 1 0 596 1 0
0 596 0 0 597 1 0
0 597 0 0 598 1 0
0 598 0 1 599 0 0
0 599 0 1 600 0 0
0 600 0 1 215 0 0
1 215 0 1 216 0 0
1 216 0 0 601 1 0
0 601 0 0 602 1 0
0 602 0 1 603 0 0
0 603 1 1 604 0 0
0 604 1 0 217 1 0
1 217 1 0 605 1 0
0 605 0 0 606 1 0
0 606 0 0 607 1 0
0 607 0 1 608 0 0
0 608 0 1 609 0 0
0 609 0 1 218 0 0
1 218 0 1 219 0 0
1 219 0 0 610 1 0
0 610 0 0 611 1 0
0 611 0 0 612 1 0
0 612 0 0 613 1 0
0 613 0 1 614 1 0
0 614 0 0 615 1 0
0 615 0 1 616 1 0
0 616 0 0 617 1 0
0 617 0 1 618 1 0
0 618 0 0 619 1 0
0 619 0 1 620 1 0
0 620 0 1 621 0 0
0 621 0 1 622 0 0
0 622 1 1 623 0 0
0 623 1 0 220 1 0
1 220 1 0 624 1 0
0 624 0 0 625 1 0
0 625 0 0 626 1 0
0 626 0 0 221 0 0
1 221 0 0 627 0 0
0 627 0 1 628 0 0
0 628 0 1 629 0 0
0 629 0 1 630 0 0
0 630 1 1 631 0 0
0 631 0 1 222 0 0
1 222 1 1 223 0 0
1 223 0 0 224 1 0
1 224 0 0 632 0 0
0 632 0 0 225 0 0
1 225 0 0 633 0 0
0 633 0 0 634 0 0
0 634 1 0 635 1 0
0 635 0 1 226 1 0
1 226 1 1 636 0 0
0 636 0 1 637 0 0
0 637 0 1 638 0 0
0 638 0 1 639 0 0
0 639 1 1 640 0 0
0 640 1 0 227 1 0
1 227 1 0 641 1 0
0 641 0 0 642 1 0
0 642 0 0 643 1 0
0 643 0 1 644 1 0
0 644 0 0 645 1 0
0 645 0 1 646 1 0
0 646 0 0 647 1 0
0 647 0 1 648 0 0
0 648 0 1 649 0 0
0 649 0 1 228 0 0
1 228 0 1 229 0 0
1 229 0 0 650 1 0
0 650 0 0 651 1 0
0 651 0 0 652 1 0
0 652 0 0 653 1 0
0 653 0 1 654 1 0
0 654 0 0 655 1 0
0 655 0 1 656 1 0
0 656 0 0 657 1 0
0 657 0 1 658 1 0
0 658 0 1 659 0 0
0 659 0 1 660 0 0
0 660 1 1 661 0 0
0 661 1 0 230 1 0
1 230 1 0 662 1 0
0 662 0 0 663 1 0
0 663 0 0 664 1 0
0 664 0 1 665 1 0
0 665 0 0 666 1 0
0 666 0 0 231 0 0
1 231 0 0 667 0 0
0 667 0 1 668 0 0
0 668 0 1 669 0 0
0 669 0 1 670 0 0
0 670 1 1 671 0 0
0 671 0 1 232 0 0
1 232 1 1 233 0 0
1 233 0 0 234 1 0
1 234 0 0 672 0 0
0 672 0 0 235 0 0
1 235 0 0 673 0 0
0 673 0 0 674 0 0
0 674 1 0 675 1 0
0 675 0 1 236 1 0
1 236 1 1 676 1 0
0 676 0 1 677 1 0
0 677 0 0 678 1 0
0 678 0 1 679 1 0
0 679 0 1 680 0 0
0 680 0 1 681 0 0
0 681 1 1 682 0 0
0 682 1 0 237 1 0
1 237 1 0 683 1 0
0 683 0 0 684 1 0
0 684 0 0 685 1 0
0 685 0 1 686 1 0
0 686 0 0 687 1 0
0 687 0 1 688 1 0
0 688 0 0 689 1 0
0 689 0 1 690 1 0
0 690 0 0 691 1 0
0 691 0 1 692 1 0
0 692 0 0 693 1 0
0 693 0 1 694 1 0
0 694 0 0 695 1 0
0 695 0 1 696 1 0
0 696 0 0 697 1 0
0 697 0 1 698 1 0
0 698 1 1 699 0 0
0 699 0 1 238 0 0
1 238 1 1 239 0 0
1 239 0 0 240 0 0
1 240 1 0 700 0 0
0 700 0 0 241 0 0
1 241 1 0 701 0 0
0 701 0 0 242 0 0
1 242 0 0 702 1 0
0 702 0 1 703 0 0
0 703 1 0 704 0 0
0 704 0 1 243 0 0
1 243 1 1 705 0 0
0 705 0 1 244 0 0
1 244 0 1 706 0 0
0 706 0 1 245 0 0
1 245 0 0 707 1 0
0 707 0 0 708 1 0
0 708 0 0 709 1 0
0 709 0 1 710 1 0
0 710 0 0 711 1 0
0 711 0 1 712 1 0
0 712 0 1 713 0 0
0 713 0 1 714 0 0
0 714 1 1 715 0 0
0 715 1 0 246 1 0
1 246 1 0 716 1 0
0 716 0 0 717 1 1
```

Made with ASCII_only's program generator

Answer (score 1):

## deflate, 79 bytes

eJyVkcsJADAIQ++ZIpD9dyxUqrGUgjlpHvglXdqCJymk1yEiaRXEIOXzuBHCiKObReUxUzYaMdt2wmTBg/FmNXndgLRbNvL7ifsLfMw6iQ==

Comment: You appear to have posted two answers in the same language. If you make an improvement to your submission it is better to edit your existing answer. Additionally, could you provide a link to the `deflate` language, as this just looks like a base64 string

Comment: I don't think deflate [counts as a programming language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2073/20748) (although I could be wrong as I don't participate on PPCG).

Comment: This is not DEFLATE, but zlib, which is DEFLATE plus a 2 byte header and a 4 byte checksum. By stripping those, you can use [the Bubblegum interpreter](https://tio.run/##bc7LSgQxEIXhvU/xOyAiSJF7p9yKT6A7cdHpdERwljPi07fJ9Cw9i1BU4KtTTqV8r5@n47aZPU9oRC1LwSjG4A0mEzxrQxXnUEOrTBNuIQaQESPPIgeRn8e3mwtkOzXPFIsGssMrSbErLeMisVLnsXfdUeZAnXZKv0TuPkTuH0R2ynXK2XF6CJEl4AxrpHlKxva2jpyZPVoIcXxxe@jO3q3n5Ur5TnlL9PiEncdcC1MaQgosluxplpTwkUmpFexrEitnqR1q8fdKhU5lQwnEMrTmaIWs4zWF/yPyni6Ftu0P "Bubblegum – Try It Online").

Comment: @NobodyNada deflate is not a programming language but we do not require that submissions be in programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

## Brainf***, <s>656</s> <s>652</s> 605 bytes

```
++[+++[<+>->>+>->-<<<<]>-]>..............>......>+.<<......>...............>.<<....>.....<....>..........>.<<..>....<.......>.......<.>....>.<<.>...<........>....<.>...<...>...>.<...<.........>....<.>...<....>...>.<...<........>....<..>...<....>...>.<...<........>....<..>...<....>...>.<...<.......>....<...>...<....>...>.<...<.......>....<...>...<....>...>.<...<......>...........<....>...>.<...<......>...........<....>...>.<...<.....>....<.....>...<....>...>.<...<.....>...<......>...<....>...>.<<.>....<..>....<...........>....>.<<..>........<.........>......>.<<......>.................>.<<......>...
```

The loop at the start initiates the tape to

```
... 032  [035]  010 ...
```

Then the rest of the code outputs those characters.

(-47 bytes thanks to orthoplex)

Comment: A shorter initialization loop can save you 47 bytes: https://tio.run/##pZJdCoAgEIQPtOgJlrlI9FBBEEEPQee3n80a7eehFhTd@dB13HqsuqGdmj4EkUKWoQIHrJPTJUq4Ej6JfQvxqkmGCFMsrxliKg6JVLXVRoD0SMccDGIiR@6YeOdP5ij9H8OufSTIRLwxdB4zmryWvPT0D2cVemmBxw7ItRBm

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL, 244 bytes

**Golfed:**

```sql
DECLARE @ varchar(max)='MfFoDEDjBDGGAcACHDACCc@CIDACDc@CHDBCDc@CHDBCDc@CGDCCDc@CGDCCDc@CFKDc@CFKDc@CEDECDc@CECFCDcADBDKdBHIfFqFC 'WHILE'!'<@
SET @=stuff(@,1,1,'')+replicate(char(35-charindex(' ',@)%2*3),ascii(@)%32)+left('
',ascii(@)/97)PRINT @
```

**Ungolfed:**

```sql
DECLARE
 @ varchar(max)='MfFoDEDjBDGGAcACHDACCc@CIDACDc@CHDBCDc@CHDBCDc@CGDCCDc@CGDCCDc@CFKDc@CFKDc@CEDECDc@CECFCDcADBDKdBHIfFqFC '

WHILE'!'<@
  SET
    @=stuff(@,1,1,'')+
    replicate(char(35-charindex(' ',@)%2*3),ascii(@)%32)+
    left('
',ascii(@)/97)
PRINT @
```

**[Try it online](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1020909/tribute-to-stan-lee)** ungolfed version